# Regular expression to extract text between square brackets

Tags: regex

Simple regex question. I have a string on the following format:

```
this is a [sample] string with [some] special words. [another one]
```

What is the regular expression to extract the words within the square brackets, ie.

```
sample
some
another one
```

Note: In my use case, brackets cannot be nested.

Answer (score 1117, accepted):

You can use the following regex **globally**:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Explanation:

- `\[` : `[` is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.
- `(.*?)` : match everything in a non-greedy way and capture it.
- `\]` : `]` is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.

Comment: The other answer's method, using `[^]]` is faster than non-greedy (`?`), and also works with regex flavours that don't support non-greedy. However, non-greedy looks nicer.

Comment: How to exclude `[` `]` from output(result)?

Comment: @MickeyTin, if you are using Java, you can group it using group(1) over just group(), so the '[]' will not go together

Comment: Can you please provide 'sed' and 'awk' examples to use this regex and extract text. Thanks.

Comment: This matches only the first occurrence

Comment: This works, but will not include additional closing brackets as part of the first capture group. To do this, use `\[(.*?]*)\]`. This will match `[[[sample]]]` such that `[[[sample]]]` is the matched string and `[[sample]]` is the first capture group. `[sample]]]` will also match `[sample]]]` with group one being `sample]]`, and `[[[sample]` will match `[[[sample]` with group one being `[[sample`

Comment: Example to match all in php.  $pattern = '#\[(.*?)\]#';

$string = 'This is a [brack] and [snares]';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

Comment: What if nested bracket contents like this.. [sample of [abc] in cd]

Comment: Note: to match all the occurrences use the method 'scan' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80357/match-all-occurrences-of-a-regex

Comment: What will be the regex for var string = "@input [ Square_bracket ]". Please Suggest

Comment: How do you exclude the brackets from the return?

Comment: @MickeyTin in JS you can use `var stringWithoutBrackets = stringWithBrackets.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'')` See [this answer from Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812077/9360197)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403148/2260920 explains a solution where if there is whitespace like enter inside the brackets.

Comment: If I want only text in the blanket and erase the outsides, how can I do?

Comment: @codaddict Man this is perfect, it saved me so much time! Thank you so much.

Comment: This does not exclude the brackets from the matches. This is the correct expression to remove the brackets: (?<=\[)[^\[\]]*(?=\])

Comment: @Nikolai That regex is invalid - it has an unterminated group

Comment: This will exclude brackets spaced across newlines.

Comment: We don't need to escape the closing bracket, because since there is no opening bracket to close, Regex treats it like a regular character.

Comment: @Bonn If you want only text in the brackets, check this [regex demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/66d286f6fdd0).

Answer (score 221):

```
(?<=\[).+?(?=\])
```

Will capture content without brackets

- `(?<=\[)` - positive lookbehind for `[`
- `.*?` - non greedy match for the content
- `(?=\])` - positive lookahead for `]`

EDIT: for nested brackets the below regex should work:

```
(\[(?:\[??[^\[]*?\]))
```

Comment: @igaurav I've checked it and it works. It will not work however in environments which does not support lookbehinds like Javascript. Maybe that is yours case?

Comment: Adam, your nested brackets solution fails when there is a string with a `.` in it...

Comment: People who write those regexps you are god damn magicians. Thank you so much!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the asker specified the output without the brackets. The currently accepted answer will return `[ '[sample]', '[some]', '[another one]' ]` while this answer returns `[ 'sample', 'some', 'another one' ]`.

Comment: The "positive lookbehind" feature may not be supported in all browsers.

Comment: Nested option was really helpful!

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: @AdamMoszczyński It works in JavaScript, here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/66d286f6fdd0).

Answer (score 104):

This should work out ok:

```
\[([^]]+)\]
```

Comment: In my use case, the bracketed text may include new lines, and this regex works, while the accepted answer does not.

Comment: what does the character class [^]] mean? What does it match?

Comment: @Richard, The ^ negates the character class. It means "any character that is not a ]".

Comment: I think it doesn't work as expected, you should use `\[([^\[\]]*)\]` to get the content in the most inner bracket. If you look into `lfjlksd [ded[ee]22]` then `\[([^]]+)\]` will get you `[ded[ee]` while the proposed expression would return `[ee]`. testede in [link](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: Can you please provide 'sed' and 'awk' examples to use this regex and extract text. Thanks.

Comment: This is the most robust way for complex situations.

Comment: This works if the content inside the brackets has whitespace.

Comment: Works perfectly in Google Sheets. Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

Can brackets be nested?

If not: `\[([^]]+)\]` matches one item, including square brackets. Backreference `\1` will contain the item to be match. If your regex flavor supports lookaround, use

```
(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])
```

This will only match the item inside brackets.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee: No, the regex can match any number of times. But some regex flavors needs to be told explicitly to apply the regex repeatedly (for example, by using the `/g` flag in JavaScript).

Answer (score 35):

To match a substring **between the *first* `[` and *last* `]`**, you may use

```
\[.*\]            # Including open/close brackets
\[(.*)\]          # Excluding open/close brackets (using a capturing group)
(?<=\[).*(?=\])   # Excluding open/close brackets (using lookarounds)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oFQMuP/2) and a [regex demo #2](https://rubular.com/r/ryNud0WM6vWPSw).

Use the following expressions to match strings **between the *closest* square brackets**:

- Including the brackets:
- `\[[^][]*]` - PCRE, Python `re`/`regex`, .NET, Golang, POSIX (grep, sed, bash)
- `\[[^\][]*]` - ECMAScript (JavaScript, C++ `std::regex`, VBA `RegExp`)
- `\[[^\]\[]*]` - Java, ICU regex
- `\[[^\]\[]*\]` - Onigmo (Ruby, requires escaping of brackets everywhere)
- Excluding the brackets:
- `(?<=\[)[^][]*(?=])` - PCRE, Python `re`/`regex`, .NET (C#, etc.), JGSoft Software
- `\[([^][]*)]` - [Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153856/3832970), [Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39102969/3832970) - *capture* the contents between the square brackets with a pair of unescaped parentheses, also see below
- `\[([^\][]*)]` - [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782646/3832970), [C++ `std::regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983337/how-to-get-only-given-captured-group-regex-c/42983684#42983684), [VBA `RegExp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303004/unable-to-apply-regex-within-vba-ie/51303462#51303462)
- `(?<=\[)[^\]\[]*(?=])` - Java regex, ICU (R `stringr`)
- `(?<=\[)[^\]\[]*(?=\])` - Onigmo (Ruby, requires escaping of brackets everywhere)

**NOTE**: `*` matches 0 or more characters, use `+` to match 1 or more to avoid empty string matches in the resulting list/array.

Whenever both lookaround support is available, the above solutions rely on them to exclude the leading/trailing open/close bracket. Otherwise, rely on capturing groups (links to most common solutions in some languages have been provided).

If you need to match **nested parentheses**, you may see the solutions in the [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433) thread and replace the round brackets with the square ones to get the necessary functionality. You should use capturing groups to access the contents with open/close bracket excluded:

- `\[((?:[^][]++|(?R))*)]` - [PHP PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/oFQMuP/1/)
- `\[((?>[^][]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>]))*)]` - [.NET demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%29%5c%5b%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%5d%29%29*%29%5d&i=%5btex1%5d+%5btext+%5b2%5d%5d)
- `\[(?:[^\]\[]++|(\g<0>))*\]` - [Onigmo (Ruby) demo](https://rubular.com/r/qxzoQHjmd8haOH)

Comment: This `\[((?>[^][]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>]))*)]` was 99.9% what I needed. By that, I mean I need everything inside the outermost brackets, but not the brackets themselves. IE, in your .Net demo link, it matches all of [text [2]], and I'd like the match to return "text [2]". However, I can get around that by just taking the match and doing a simple substring that skips the first and last characters.

I am curious if it is possible to modify that regex ever so slightly to automatically omit the outermost brackets.

Comment: @B.O.B. You need to get the Group 1 value, see [the C# demo online](https://ideone.com/fKwvMo).

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that I try in my demo code that I am using (before I move it into the real project). Edit: that was exactly it! Thanks for the expert and exceptionally fast response).

Answer (score 25):

If you do not want to include the brackets in the match, here's the regex: `(?<=\[).*?(?=\])`

## **Let's break it down**

The `.` matches any character except for line terminators. The `?=` is a *positive lookahead*. A positive lookahead finds a string when a certain string comes after it. The `?<=` is a *positive lookbehind*. A positive lookbehind finds a string when a certain string precedes it. To quote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973495#2973495),

> ## Look ahead positive (?=)
>
> Find expression A where expression B follows:
>
> ## `A(?=B)`
>
> ## Look behind positive (?<=)
>
> Find expression A where expression B
>   precedes:
>
> ## `(?<=B)A`

## **The Alternative**

If your regex engine does not support lookaheads and lookbehinds, then you can use the regex `\[(.*?)\]` to capture the innards of the brackets in a group and then you can manipulate the group as necessary.

#### **How does this regex work?**

The parentheses capture the characters in a group. The `.*?` gets all of the characters between the brackets (except for line terminators, unless you have the `s` flag enabled) in a way that is not greedy.

Comment: Fyi, this breaks Safari if the version is < 16.4 - https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Answer (score 20):

Just in case, you might have had [unbalanced brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses), you can likely design some expression with recursion similar to,

```
\[(([^\]\[]+)|(?R))*+\]
```

which of course, it would relate to the language or RegEx engine that you might be using.

### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/vrRjqE/1/)

---

Other than that,

```
\[([^\]\[\r\n]*)\]
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/BPvoKj/1/)

or,

```
(?<=\[)[^\]\[\r\n]*(?=\])
```

#### [RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/Ya2tpx/1/)

are good options to explore.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MMqvLR/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/MMqvLR/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```js
const regex = /\[([^\]\[\r\n]*)\]/gm;
const str = `This is a [sample] string with [some] special words. [another one]
This is a [sample string with [some special words. [another one
This is a [sample[sample]] string with [[some][some]] special words. [[another one]]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

### Source

[Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)

Comment: This answer is criminally underrated in that it provides an education and a taste of the power of finite state machines.

Answer (score 13):

`(?<=\[).*?(?=\])` works good as per explanation given above. Here's a Python example:

```
import re 
str = "Pagination.go('formPagination_bottom',2,'Page',true,'1',null,'2013')"
re.search('(?<=\[).*?(?=\])', str).group()
"'formPagination_bottom',2,'Page',true,'1',null,'2013'"
```

Comment: You should always use code formatting for regexes, wherever they appear.  If the regex is in the text rather than a code block, you can use backticks to format them. ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting))

Comment: Also, the question was about square brackets (`[]`), not parentheses.

Comment: It doesn't work, if there is a nested braket. You can see it in this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/a91fb93c6905).

Answer (score 11):

The @Tim Pietzcker's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403158/2535933)

> ```
> (?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])
> ```

is almost the one I've been looking for. But there is one issue that some legacy browsers can fail on positive lookbehind.
So I had to made my day by myself :). I manged to write this:

```
/([^[]+(?=]))/g
```

Maybe it will help someone.

```js
console.log("this is a [sample] string with [some] special words. [another one]".match(/([^[]+(?=]))/g));
```

Comment: perfect answer I was looking for

Comment: Slick rick! Worked great and good use of running a code snippet to show how it works. Great answer.

Comment: the second one, doesn't work, if there is a nested braket. Check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/2845c6d792c7).

Answer (score 6):

**if you want fillter only small alphabet letter between square bracket a-z**

```
(\[[a-z]*\])
```

**if you want small and caps letter a-zA-Z**

```
(\[[a-zA-Z]*\])
```

**if you want small  caps and  number letter a-zA-Z0-9**

```
(\[[a-zA-Z0-9]*\])
```

**if you want everything between square bracket**

**if you want text , number and symbols**

```
(\[.*\])
```

Answer (score 4):

This code will extract the content between square brackets and parentheses

```
(?:(?<=\().+?(?=\))|(?<=\[).+?(?=\]))

(?: non capturing group
(?<=\().+?(?=\)) positive lookbehind and lookahead to extract the text between parentheses
| or
(?<=\[).+?(?=\]) positive lookbehind and lookahead to extract the text between square brackets
```

Answer (score 4):

In R, try:

```
x <- 'foo[bar]baz'
str_replace(x, ".*?\\[(.*?)\\].*", "\\1")
[1] "bar"
```

Comment: ..or `gsub(pat, "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)`, where `pat` is the regular expression you provided..

Comment: This solution is excellent in the way that it "extracts" the content inside the brackets *if there is one*, otherwise you get the input.

Answer (score 4):

I needed including newlines and including the brackets

`\[[\s\S]+\]`

Comment: I needed this, but it does not end on the first occurrence of "]"

Answer (score 3):

```
([[][a-z \s]+[]])
```

Above should work given the following explaination

- characters within square brackets[] defines characte class which means pattern should match atleast one charcater mentioned within square brackets
- \s specifies a space
- + means atleast one of the character mentioned previously to +.

Comment: In sensitive cases `A-Z` should add to pattern : `([[][a-zA-Z \s]+[]])` ; I think it's good way, while `\ ` in regex patterns that defines in string marks ( " and ' ) and mixing up newbies by backslash handling in " or ' usages!

Comment: the only answer that worked for me for C++ regex (except im doing it with quotations instead of brackets). `std::regex pattern{R"(["][a-zA-Z \s]+["])"};`

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to match and select a string containing one or more dots inside square brackets like "**[fu.bar]**" use the following:

```
(?<=\[)(\w+\.\w+.*?)(?=\])
```

[Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5b%29%28%5cw%2b%5c.%5cw%2b.*%3f%29%28%3f%3d%5c%5d%29&i=%5bfoo.bar%5d%0d%0a%5bfoo.foo.bar%5d%0d%0a%5b.bar%5d%0d%0a%5bfoo.%5d%0d%0a%5b.foo.%5d%0d%0a)