# Regular expression to match text between either square or curly brackets

Tags: regex

Related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets), I have a string on the following format:

```
this {is} a [sample] string with [some] {special} words. [another one]
```

What is the regular expression to extract the words within either square **or** curly brackets, ie.

```
{is}
[sample]
[some]
{special}
[another one]
```

Note: In my use case, brackets cannot be nested. I would also like to keep the enclosing characters, so that I can tell the difference between them when processing the results.

Comment: What if the string is `blah [{] blah {]}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply or (`|`) the different things you wish to match together:

`\[.*?\]|\{.*?\}`

Answer (score 2):

This one seems to work:

```
[[{].*?[}\]]
```

Or this one:

```
\[.*?\]|{.*?}
```

If you want to catch the cases mentioned in the comments below.

You can use an online regex tester to try these things out.  I think http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is one of the more user-friendly options.

Comment: This will fail in the case of [ ... }.

Comment: Edited to remove an extraneous `\`.

Comment: @Carl, no he said [{foo} [bar]] (example of nesting) didn't happen.

Comment: Brackets can't be nested means to me  [ [  ] ], which is a classic case that regular expressions fail on.

Comment: His example string doesn't contain such a thing.  I will edit to change that.

Comment: @Carl: You can match a [ with `\[`. Why use `[[]`?

Comment: @Kenny, changed - I was just editing my previous entry, should be fixed already.