# Javascript Regex match text between tildes

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, serverside-javascript

I feel like an idiot because I've spent a long time trying to find a regex that will work.

String: `~05276~^~0500~^~Turkey...`

The ... means that there can be an unlimited number of characters after.  What I want is the first tilde delimited number without the tildes.  I'm trying to pull some data from a text file, and I think that I can figure the rest out if I can understand how to do this.

Here's my regex as it stands: `/^~([\d]+)~/`

This is what I'm getting:

```
[ '~05276~',
 '05276',
 index: 0,
 input: '~05276~^~0500~^~Turkey...' ]
```

When I use the g operator (`/^~([\d]+)~/g`), I'm only getting the `~05276~`, and what I want is the `05726` (no tildes).

I've found a few different posts and resources, but I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working as I expect.  Here's what I found:

[Javascript regex - how to get text between curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354224/javascript-regex-how-to-get-text-between-curly-brackets)

Is JavaScript/NodeJS capable of this?

Edit:

Here's my code:

```
lineReader.eachLine(file, function (line) {
    var entry = {};

    entry.id = line.match(/^~([\d]+)~/);

    console.log(entry);
});
```

lineReader is working properly and returns a line like in my example string above.

Comment: Try losing the '^'. You should get an array of integer values delimited by '~'.

Comment: The "match()" function returns **an array** based on the match. Check the documentation!!

Comment: I don't mind getting an array, but why am I getting the two, practically identical results in the first one (without g)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'r regex is (almost) fine, but you're probably not using it right.  Here's what I'd do if I wanted an array of the numbers:

```
 var array = [];
 yourString.replace(/~(\d+)~/g, function(_, n) { array.push(n); });
```

What you really don't need is that leading "^" anchor.

Comment: I don't want an array, I just want the first one.  I'll put my code up.

Comment: You just want the first one?  But you're getting the first one already in the results you posted ... I just don't understand then. If you just want the first one, then the "g" modifier is clearly unnecessary.

Comment: Well, with the "g" modifier, I'm getting a single string surrounded by tildes.  I don't want the tildes, just the number.  I suppose I could do a substring or something else to trim them off, but I'd like to find a way through regex.

Comment: You really should check [the documentation for the RegExp methods you want to use.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: I understand why I'm getting an array.  I've used regex in other places to split text, but why am I getting the tildes? I thought the parentheses captured only what's inside. It should match the whole string but only add the \d+ data to the result, right?

Comment: My apologies.  I had thought that I was getting two matches (one with the delimiter and one without), but I guess the results showed the string that matched followed by the string that was captured.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The array you get has a first element `m[0]` which holds the _overall_ mattch (which includes the tildes), the next element `m[1]` contains the contents of the first capture group, which is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the regex `/\d+/` in order to match the first number after tilde in your example. Your method would then be:

```
lineReader.eachLine(file, function (line) {
    var entry = {};
    entry.id = line.match(/\d+/);
    console.log(entry);
});
```

With input `"~05276~^~0500~^~Turkey"` you will get the result `"05276"`.

Regarding the array answer you get, it's because you have parentheses, i.e. a capture group. If it's a match the group captured, starting at the leftmost parenthesis -- `(\d+)` in your case -- will reside in the second slot of the result array. The first slot has the full match, which in your case includes tildes.