# Dealing with multiple possible indexOf()

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

Ok, let's say you have a string: `"(hello) (world) (something) (number 4)"`
And in javascript, you wanted to get the contents between the brackets in chronological order. You can use `indexOf()` but how can you deal with multiple possibility.

Comment: Check this: [Javascript regex - how to get text between curly brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354224/javascript-regex-how-to-get-text-between-curly-brackets)

Comment: What do you mean with "chronological" order?

Comment: from num 1 to the last

Answer (score 1):

using `match` and `map` may be an idea:

```
"(hello) (world) (something) (number 4)"
 .match(/\(.+?\)/g)
 .map(function(a){return a.replace(/[\(\)]/g,'');})
//=> ["hello", "world", "something", "number 4"]
```

See [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `Array.prototype.map` method, also offers a shim for older browsers

Comment: did the `map` method replace all `()` with nothing? and how did you put it in an array?

Comment: The `match` methods' result is an array containing all parenthesized words of the string (as per the regular expression `/\(.+?\)/g`). The `map` method replaces the parentheses of every element of that array with an empty string.