# How to remove square brackets in string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

`['abc','xyz']` – this string I want turn into `abc,xyz` using regex in javascript. I want to replace both open close square bracket & single quote with empty string ie `""`.

Comment: Where does this string come from? Is this JSON or something similar?

Comment: Could the square brackets be nested? `['abc',['def','ghi'],'jkl']` If so, what should the result be?

Comment: Is this a JavaScript literal? What do you do with `['ab\'c', 'xy\\z']`?

Answer (score 103):

Use this regular expression to match square brackets or single quotes:

```
/[\[\]']+/g
```

Replace with the empty string.

```js
console.log("['abc','xyz']".replace(/[\[\]']+/g,''));
```

Comment: mind explaining the regular expressions at work here?

Comment: @Zypps987 `[...]` in regexp is used to define a set of characters to match, they're part of the regexp "vocabulary". Consequently, if you want to match `[` and `]` characters, you need to escape them so that they're interpreted as simple characters. The `+` means that you don't want to match this set only once, but for the whole string. Which results in `/[\[\]']+` if you want to catch every `[`, `]` or `'` characters.

Comment: The first bracket within the character class doesn't have to be escaped. Only `(/[[\]]/g,'')` is needed, as @ithkuil suggests below.

Comment: It is written for javascript @adamrowe

Answer (score 21):

`str.replace(/[[\]]/g,'')`

Answer (score 14):

here you go

```
var str = "['abc',['def','ghi'],'jkl']";
//'[\'abc\',[\'def\',\'ghi\'],\'jkl\']'
str.replace(/[\[\]']/g,'' );
//'abc,def,ghi,jkl'
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't even need string substitution for that. If your original string is JSON, try:

```
js> a="['abc','xyz']"
['abc','xyz']
js> eval(a).join(",")
abc,xyz
```

Be careful with `eval`, of course.

Comment: It's not JSON because JSON uses double quotes for strings, not single quotes. See: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```js
str.replace(/[[\]]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just here to propose an alternative that I find more readable.

```
/\[|\]/g
```

JavaScript implementation:

```js
let reg = /\[|\]/g

str.replace(reg,'')
```

As other people have shown, all you have to do is list the `[` and `]` characters, but because they are special characters you have to escape them with `\`.

I personally find the character group definition using `[]` to be confusing because it uses the same special character you're trying to replace.

Therefore using the `|` (OR) operator you can more easily distinguish the special characters in the regex from the literal characters being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

we can easily replace **[** and **]** using **replace()** method in javascript in the following way.

```js
console.log("['abc','xyz']".replace('[','').replace(']', ''));
```