# Regex to get the text between two text boundaries and the boundaries too

Tags: php, regex

Building on this question: [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

```
this is a [sample] string with [some] special words. [another one]
```

I need to extract the text between [sample] and [some] plus the two boundaries too. In other word I want the regex that matches **[sample] string with [some]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\[sample\].*?\[some\]/
```

You just need to escape the square brackets and use a lazy match between your markers.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?335dt).

If the text can be on several rows, you need to enable the dotall mode additionally with the `s` modifier:

```
/\[sample\].*?\[some\]/s
```

this makes the `.` also match newline characters, what it is not doing by default.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?335e0)