# preg_match, str_replace and all that jazz

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string which contains several keywords in square backets which I want to identify, extract, and replace with something else:

For example:

> 'You will win [winnings] or [slice].'

I want to identify all the terms within the squares, take those terms and replace them with certain values.

So it should end up like this:

> 'You will win 100 or 95%.'

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$replacements = array(
    'winnings' => '100'
    , 'slice'  => '95%'
    , 'foobar' => 'Sean Bright'
);

$subject = '[foobar], You will win [winnings] or [slice]!';

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[([^\]]+)\]/',
    function ($x) use ($replacements) {
        if (array_key_exists($x[1], $replacements))
            return $replacements[$x[1]];
        return '';
    },
    $subject);

echo $result;
```

Note that this will completely fall apart if you have unbalanced brackets (i.e. `[[foo]`)

For PHP versions less than 5.3:

```
$replacements = array(
    'winnings' => '100'
    , 'slice'  => '95%'
    , 'foobar' => 'Sean Bright'
);

function do_replacement($x)
{
    global $replacements;

    if (array_key_exists($x[1], $replacements))
        return $replacements[$x[1]];
    return '';
}

$subject = '[foobar], You will win [winnings] or [slice]!';

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[([^\]]+)\]/',
    'do_replacement',
    $subject);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Like the look of this, but I'm getting an error with the code?

Comment: What error are you getting?  I've tested this locally and it works.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/slimming/public_html/aardvark.php on line 12
which is :
function ($x) use ($replacements) {

Comment: What version of PHP?  Must be older than 5.3

Comment: Added a solution for PHP < 5.3

Answer (score 3):

piece of cake

```
$search = array('[winnings]', '[slice]');
$replace = array(100, '95%');

echo str_replace($search, $replace, 'You will win [winnings] or [slice].');
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to use a regex to find matches:

```
$content = "You will win [winnings] or [slice].";
preg_match_all('/\[([a-z]+)\]/i', $content, $matches);

$content = str_replace($matches[0], array('100', '95%'), $content);

var_dump($content);
```