# generating unique Id in java

Tags: java, string

I wanted to take a string such as

```
[item.a.1234] is very close to [item.a.2345]
```

and print out only the "item" to the screen...how might I do that.

So far I have:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(istream);
        String output = bReader.readLine();
        while (output != null){
            System.out.println(output);
            output = bReader.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me:

```
[item.a.1234] is very close to [item.a.2345]
```

I want:

```
item.a.1234,item.a.2345
```

without the word in between the "Items"...any suggestions?

Comment: *"...any suggestions?"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that actually attempts it!  Given the `String` can be hard-coded, it seems that source above is almost entirely unrelated.

Comment: seperate your strings using String manipulation methods. I think the openening and closing brackets are nice indicators for the extraction of your items

Comment: And how is this related to "generating unique ids" ?

Comment: If you want to generate unique IDs, as your title suggests, look at UUIDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions. Here is a regexp that does what you need - [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets).

Answer (score 0):

Solution in pseudo-code.

1. Replace all occurrences of `[` with ''.
2. Replace all occurrences of `]` with ''.
3. Split that string on ' ' (the space character).
4. Print the first element of the resulting array.
5. Print a comma.
6. Print the last element in the array.

Comment: this should print [item.a.1234],[item.a.2345] but not item.a.1234,item.a.2345

Comment: @Ashish  Oops!  Missed that part.  See edit.