# Extract data between characters using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string something like `[[user.system.first_name]][[user.custom.luid]] blah blah`

I want to match `user.system.first_name` and `user.custom.luid`

I built `/\[\[(\S+)\]\]/` but it is matching `user.system.first_name]][[user.custom.luid`.

Any idea where I am doing wrong?

Comment: `/\[\[(\S+?)\]\]/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it non-greedy as

```
/\[\[(\S+?)\]\]/
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tO0dW1/1)**

Answer (score 3):

Make it non-greedy using `?`  to match as few input characters as possible. That your regex will be **[`/\[\[(\S+?)\]\]/`](https://regex101.com/r/sB1uZ0/1)**

```js
var str = '[[user.system.first_name]][[user.custom.luid]] blah blah'
var reg = /\[\[(\S+?)\]\]/g,
  match, res = [];

while (match = reg.exec(str))
  res.push(match[1]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need 2 separate matches use:

```
\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hK2oY5/6)

Answer (score 1):

I think `/[^[]+?(?=]])/g` is one fast regex. Turns out to be completed in 44 steps

```
[^[]+?(?=]])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XoMdyOZ_lSmrKcnt)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pR7qX6/1)

```js
var s = "[[user.system.first_name]][[user.custom.luid]]",
    m = s.match(/[^[]+?(?=]])/g);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(m,null,2) + "</pre>") ;
```