# Find all string matches with Regex golang

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to return an array, or slice, with all the matches for a specific regex expression against a string. The string is:

```
{city}, {state} {zip}
```

I want to return an array with all the matches of strings between curly braces. I have tried using the [regexp](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp) package to accomplish this but cannot figure out how to return what I am looking for. This is my current code:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile("/({[^}]*})/")
matches := r.FindAllString("{city}, {state} {zip}", -1)
```

But, all it returns is an empty slice every time no matter what I try.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First, you do not need the regex delimiters. Second, it is a good idea to use raw string literals to define a regex pattern where you need to use only 1 backslash to escape regex metacharacters. Third, the capturing group is only necessary if you need to get the values without `{` and `}`, thus, you may remove it to get `{city}`, `{state}` and `{zip}`.

You may use [`FindAllString`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString) to get all matches:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`{[^{}]*}`)
matches := r.FindAllString("{city}, {state} {zip}", -1)
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/wkBP1t28deD).

To only get the parts between curly braces use [`FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) with a pattern that contains capturing parentheses, `{([^{}]*)}`:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`{([^{}]*)}`)
matches := r.FindAllStringSubmatch("{city}, {state} {zip}", -1)
for _, v := range matches {
    fmt.Println(v[1])
}
```

See [this Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/yX920ZUXP81).

**Regex details**

- `{` - a literal `{` char
- `([^{}]*)`- a capturing group that matches any 0 or more (due to the `*` quantifier) characters other than `{` and `}` (`[^...]` is a negated character class matching any char but the one(s) specified between `[^` and `]`)
- `}` - a literal `}` char