# Go regex to search for Jira during clause which contains escaped quotes

Tags: regex, go, jql

Regex 101 shows this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/lWroWE/2) as valid:

```
/during.*\(\"\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\",.*\"\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\"\)|during.*\(startOfMonth\(\),.*now\(\)\)/gm
```

but using it in Go, it does not appear to work when attempting `FindAllString` ([Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2UO2q8rSezS?v=goprev))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var duringRegex *regexp.Regexp

func init() {
    duringRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`/during.*\(\"\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\",.*\"\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\"\)|during.*\(startOfMonth\(\),.*now\(\)\)/gm`)
}

func main() {
    jqlDuringBeginningOfMonthToEndOfMonth := "project = SWB AND status changed from \"In Regression\" to (Done) during (\"2022-09-01\", \"2022-09-30\")"
    jqlDuringStartOfMonthToNow := "project = SWB AND status changed from \"In Regression\" to (Done) during (startOfMonth(), now())"
    fmt.Printf("result: %s", duringRegex.FindAllString(jqlDuringBeginningOfMonthToEndOfMonth, -1))
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("result: %s", duringRegex.FindAllString(jqlDuringStartOfMonthToNow, -1))
}
```

Run shows:

```
result: []
result: []
Program exited.
```

I suspect this behaviour has to do with escaped quotes in the JQL strings. Changing the JQL strings to use single quotes did not make a difference in the results, either.

Comment: You use backticks ``. It is a special kind of string literals where you don't need to escape quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Pak Uula for the tip. Also this answer: [Find all string matches with Regex golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102902/find-all-string-matches-with-regex-golang)

The solution is to not use boundaries on the regex, and also as Pak mentioned, the back-ticks in the regex take care of the quotes; so no need to escape those. Solution in [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/D0WOTMXdPQI?v=goprev)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var duringRegex *regexp.Regexp

func init() {
    duringRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`during.*\("\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])",.*"\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"\)|during.*\(startOfMonth\(\),.*now\(\)\)`)
}

func main() {
    jqlDuringBeginningOfMonthToEndOfMonth := "project = SWB AND status changed from \"In Regression\" to (Done) during (\"2022-09-01\", \"2022-09-30\")"
    jqlDuringStartOfMonthToNow := "project = SWB AND status changed from \"In Regression\" to (Done) during (startOfMonth(), now())"
    fmt.Printf("result: %s", duringRegex.FindAllString(jqlDuringBeginningOfMonthToEndOfMonth, -1))
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("result: %s", duringRegex.FindAllString(jqlDuringStartOfMonthToNow, -1))
}
```

Run shows:

```
result: [during ("2022-09-01", "2022-09-30")]
result: [during (startOfMonth(), now())]
Program exited.
```