# How to get only given captured group <regex> c++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I want to extract tag's inner content. From the following string:

```
<tag1 val=123>Hello</tag1>
```

I just want to get

```
Hello
```

What I do:

```
string s = "<tag1 val=123>Hello</tag1>";
regex re("<tag1.*>(.*)</tag1>");
smatch matches;
bool b = regex_match(s, matches, re);
```

But it returns two matches:

```
<tag1 val=123>Hello</tag1>
Hello
```

And when I try to get only 1st captured group like this:

```
"<tag1.*>(.*)</tag1>\1"
```

I get zero matches.

Please, advise.

Comment: You only get 1 match that contains two submatches: 1) whole match, 2) capture group 1 value. The capture can be accessed with `matches[1].str()` or `matches.str(1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`regex_match`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/)  returns only a single match, with all the capturing group submatches (their number depends on how many groups there are in the pattern).

Here, you only get 1 match that contains two submatches: 1) whole match, 2) capture group 1 value.

To obtain the contents of the capturing group, you need to access the `smatches` object second element, `matches[1].str()` or `matches.str(1)`

Note that when you write `"<tag1.*>(.*)</tag1>\1"`, the `\1`  is not parsed as a *backreference*, but as a char with octal code 1. Even if you defined a *backreference* (as `"<tag1.*>(.*)</tag1>\\1"`) you would require the whole text captured with the capturing group 1 to be repeated after `</tag1>`  - that is definitely not what you want. Actually, I doubt this regex is any good, at least, you need to replace `".*"`  with `"[\\s\\S]*?"`, but it is still a fragile approach to parse HTML with regex.