# Need a regular expression match for finding and replacing a pattern

Tags: ruby

Here is my string:

```
string = "abcdef.sfdsf_3asafds-fdsfd;info=<http://www.amazon.com:8080/abc/ads/asdf>;tag=abc123;val=hello"
```

My goal using gsub/sub in ruby to replace:

```
info=<http://www.amazon.com:8080/abc/ads/asdf>
```

with:

```
info=<private-url>
```

I tried a few attempts using regexp but they are buggy. Any advice?

Comment: The important thing to remember here is showing your attempts helps considerably. You may be as little as one character away from a solution and it's easy for someone to spot and fix that than to start from nothing.

Comment: will it always be the same base url? (amazon.com)

Comment: No, it can be anything. My need is to "replace" the complete info= with a user provided url.

Comment: @tadman, a very simple solution that I tried was `<.*>`. But this is buggy, since the user can also change the info= with a different string.

Comment: Or something like `string.sub(/<[^<>]+>/,"<private-url>")`

Comment: `string.sub(/info=\<.*?\>/,"info=<private-url>")`

Comment: `string.gsub(/info=<.+?>/, 'info=<private-url>')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex to do it can be `/<(.*?)>/`

This will match everything inside `< >` (including the `< >` signals).

**Keep in mind that this will match the first occurrence on string.**

You can check the explanation for the regex on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets).

You can also check it on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/aCxFbfOm41), a great tool to test ruby regex on fly.

In order to replace the match result in `Ruby` you can try something like

`2.4.0 :024 > string.sub(/<(.*?)>/, '<your_url>')
 => "abcdef.sfdsf_3asafds-fdsfd;info=<your_url>;tag=abc123;val=hello"`

This can be used on this string, but you need to adapt it on your use if there are more `< >` signals on the string.

Comment: It's worth noting here that `<.*>` means *longest* possible match, while `<.*?>` means *shortest* possible. The difference here is how you avoid your expression getting too "greedy".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't worte that becaus I've linked another question that explains it. Should I copy/paste it here for better understanding for future viewers?