# Regular expression to extract specific text between brackets

Tags: regex

[I have read up on other questions/answers that get the text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets) - but what if I only want to get those brackets with specific text.

For example, the string I have is in the following format:

```
{this is a}{string with text}{i want this bracket}{only}
```

I want to extract all of the `{i want this bracket}` by searching upon `want` and `bracket` only. The `i` and `this` could be random text, example `{gjddnsgwantjgnsagjbracket}`

I can split them up into groups by doing the following:

`/\{(.*?)\}/g`

But I cannot for the love of me search within said capture groups to extract the bracket I want.

Comment: Something like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/XJ0Rkh/1)?

Comment: @Gurman, that is exactly what I need - put an answer in! Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanDavis Posted as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`{(?=[^}]*want)(?=[^}]*bracket)[^}]+}`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJ0Rkh/1)

**Explanation:**

- `{` - matches `{` literally
- `(?=[^}]*want)` - positive lookahead to validate for the presence of `want` before the `}`
- `(?=[^}]*bracket)` - positive lookahead to validate for the presence of `want` before the `}`
- `[^}]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is not a `}`
- `}` - matches a `}` literally

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
$ echo '{i want this bracket}' | grep -E '{[^}]*want[^}]*bracket[^}]*}'
{i want this bracket}

$ echo '{gjddnsgwantjgnsagjbracket[^}]*}' | grep -E '{[^}]*want[^}]*bracket[^}]*}'
{gjddnsgwantjgnsagjbracket}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, @Bill. How does this cope if `want` is in another bracket as well as it's own with `bracket`? Will it return two brackets? If so, is there a way to make it only return the bracket with `want and bracket` in? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It will not match words without both words in them. e.g. `$ echo '{gjddnsgwantjgnsagjb}' | grep -E '{[^}]*want[^}]*bracket}'` results in no match.