# Extract string in parentheses using c#

Tags: c#, regex, parentheses

I have a string `---TIMESTAMP Tue, 24 Oct 2017 02:11:56 -0400 [1508825516987]---`

I want to get the value within the `[]` (i.e. `1508825516987`)

How can I get the value using Regex?

Comment: Please show what you've already tried. It should be fairly simple to capture values within `[` and `]`. (It's not clear that you actually want a split - it looks like you just want to match and then extract the value from a group.)

Comment: Tried (TIMESTAMP [a-zA-Z])+ but no luck. I know this is wrong and I am learner in the Regex.

Comment: So show the exact code that you tried, and the results rather than just "didn't work".

Comment: (Edit the question rather than just putting it in comments.)

Comment: Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline); Use [RegExr](https://regexr.com) to learn to create regular expressions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

Comment: @Jon Skeet  I tried this code     string test = "---TIMESTAMP Tue, 24 Oct 2017 02:11:56 -0400 [1508825516987]---";
            string pattern = @"TIMESTAMP\s(*?)";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            Match match = regex.Match(test);
            string result = match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : "";

Comment: The answer is in the duplicated question, see @Odrai comment. Also http://regexstorm.net/ is a handy site for testing regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation:

- `\[` : `[` is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.
- `(.*?)` : match everything in a non-greedy way and capture it.
- `\]` : `]` is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.

Source of explanation: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403159/1974344)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string txt = "---TIMESTAMP Tue, 24 Oct 2017 02:11:56 -0400 [1508825516987]---";

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match match = regex.Match(txt);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            String extract = match.Groups[i].ToString();
            Console.Write(extract.ToString());
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Links to learn to create regular expressions:

- [Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/)
- [RegExr](https://regexr.com)

**Update 1:**

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^---.*\[(.*?)\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

- ^ is start of string
- --- are your (start) characters
- .* is any char between --- and [

Comment: In my string array I may have lot of text contains [], but I want to get the value when the line starts with ---Timestamp

Comment: @Karthikeyan You are welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the greedy `*?` and not the reluctant equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the outcome what you want!

```
 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("---TIMESTAMP Tue, 24 Oct 2017 02:11:56 -0400 [1508825516987]---", @"\[(.*?)\]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
 Match mat = matches[0];
 string val = mat.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
```

whereas the string **val** will contain the value what you required.

Comment: ---TIMESTAMP Tue, 24 Oct 2017 02:11:56 -0400 [1508825516987]--- How can I get this value 24 Oct 2017 02:11:56 from this string by using regex.

Comment: You can get this value 24 Oct 2017 02:11:56 by using this @"\,(.*?)-" unicode character which can separate the content which you needed by using regex.