# sub command to extract data and split data frame column

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Trying to extract data from data frame 
**Sample Column:**

```
Second
Daughter (Birth)
No Relation
Son (Adopted)
```

**Desired output (two column):**

```
Data1            Data2
Daughter        (Birth)
No relation
Son             (Adopted)
```

**using this command but not getting the results:**

```
as.data.frame(sub(".*\\w+[^)]*?(\\w+)\\).*", "\\1", test1$second))
```

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: `library(stringr); str_extract(test1$second, "\\((.*?)\\)")` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets).

Comment: Do you really want the parentheses around the data in `Data2`?

Comment: Yes, Parentheses is a part of the data.

Comment: @Ronak Shah Thanks for your suggestions, based on above suggestions, I was able to get the desired results. Please let me know if this can can be improved or optimized to something smaller.  `code` test1 <- data.frame(second = c("Daughter (Birth)", "No Relation", "Son (Adopted)"))
test1[2] <- data.frame(gsub("\\((.*?)\\)", "", test1$second))
test1[3] <- data.frame(str_extract(test1$second, "\\((.*?)\\)"))
colnames(test1)[2] <- "data1"
colnames(test1)[3] <- "data2" `code`

Comment: `test1$data2 <- str_extract(test1$second, "\\((.*?)\\)")` should do it.