# How to use regex capturing group in bash correctly?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I've loaded some strings into variable "result". The strings look like this:

```
school/proj_1/file1.txt
school/proj_1/file2.txt
school/proj_1/file3.txt
```

I try to get only the name after the last slash, so file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt is the desirable result for me. I use this piece of code

```
for i in $result
do
  grep "school/proj_1/(.*)" $i
done
```

but it doesn't work. I feel that the regex would work for Python with the caputuring group I created, but I can't really wrap my head around how to use capturing groups in bash or if it is even possible at all.

I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm very new to scripting in bash.

Comment: With `grep`, if you don't pass the `-E` flag, you will need to escape any characters that would have a special regex meaning.  So I think either `grep -E "school/proj_1/(.*)" $i` or `grep "school/proj_1/\(.*\)" $i` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a simple approach with a [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) operation:

```
echo "${i##*/}"
```

> `${string##substring}`
>     Deletes longest match of *`$substring`* from *front* of *`$string`*.

Or using a regex in Bash, you may get the capturing groups like

```
result=("school/proj_1/file1.txt" "school/proj_1/file2.txt" "school/proj_1/file3.txt")
rx='school/proj_1/(.*)'
for i in "${result[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$i" =~ $rx ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Sd4Fpr). Here, `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` is the contents inside capturing group #1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

#### variable declaration :

```
$ result="school/proj_1/file1.txt
school/proj_1/file2.txt
school/proj_1/file3.txt"
```

#### Commands :

(all as *one-liners*)

```
$ grep -oP "school/proj_1/\K.*" "$i" <<< "$result"
```

or

```
$ awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' <<< "$result
```

or

```
$ sed 's|.*/||' <<< "$result"
```

or if number of sub dirs are fixed :

```
$ cut -d'/' -f3 <<< "$result"
```

#### Output :

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```