# Regular Expression to replace . between "

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I want to replace all occurences of the character . in all strings in a solution

These strings look like this:

```
string sentence = "Hello world. Good bye world";
```

And I want them all to look like this:

```
string sentence = "Hello world_ Good bye world";
```

I want to do it with a regular Expression. I tried with similar approaches as the described here: [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets) and I read the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio but I can't figure out how I can continue.

Edit: I am using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? Older versions of Visual Studio supported a different regex syntax.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: If there is every more than one '.' in-between the quotes I don't think you're going to have a catch all solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=(?<="|[\.](?<=".*))[^\.]*?)(\.)(?=.*")
```

It seems that this pattern works in .NET regex because the engine support varable length lookbehind.   [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3C%3D%22%7C%5B%5C.%5D%28%3F%3C%3D%22.*%29%29%5B%5E%5C.%5D*%3F%29%28%5C.%29%28%3F%3D.*%22%29&i=..string%20.sentence.%20%3D%20.%22.Hell.o%20world..%20Good.%20bye.%20world.%22.%3B.%20&r=_%0D%0A%0D%0A) (click [table] and [context] tab to check replace result )

[Test string]

```
..string .sentence. = .".Hell.o world.. Good. bye. world.".;.
```

replace captured character with "_"

```
..string .sentence. = ."_​Hell_​o world_​_​ Good_​ bye_​ world_​".;.
```

- (\.) : capturing target.(literal period(.))
- (?=.*") : quote existence after the period being captured.
- (?<=(?<="|[\.](?<=".*))[^\.]*?) : preceding quote existence and possibly existence of a period with any non-dot characters preceded by a quote before the period being captured

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 Edit/Find and Replace. You will probably find further constraints but should get you started.

In find what:

```
(string\s[^\s]+\s+=\s+"[^\.]+)(\.)(\s*[^"]+")
```

In replace with:

```
$1_$3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
(?<=(?<!\\)"(\"|[^"])*)\.(?=(\"|[^"])*")
```

...which basically looks for any period preceded by zero or more of any character not a quote or a quote preceded by a backslash, and then preceded by a quote that does not have a leading backslash. That same period is followed by zero or more of any character not a quote or a quote preceded by a backslash, and then followed by a quote not preceded by a backslash.

Keep in mind that this is not foolproof--it does not handle verbatim strings (i.e. @""). You could probably tweak it to accommodate such.

Also, the replacement is just the character you want to change to (i.e. underscore).

Answer (score -1):

A simple expression like:

```
\.
```

Should do the trick.

Try using this:

```
String sentence = "Hello world. Good bye world";
sentence.replaceAll(\\.\g,"_");
```

Edit: Added global flag to regex.

Comment: This does not take into account _in all strings in a solution_