# sheets REGEXEXTRACT - extract text between square brackets

Tags: google-sheets, re2

I have a cell in E13 which contains numbers and numbers between brackets.
What I want to acheive is to match the number and copy to another cell and delete the match from E13.

E13

```
0:08.63 [6]
```

I want E13 to be

```
0:08.63
```

And in M13 I want

```
6
```

Based on this example https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "\(([A-Za-z]+)\)")
```

I tried this in M13

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(E13,\([[0-9]+]\))
```

Then based on this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403159/461887

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(E13,\[(.*?)\])
```

But in both cases I just get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just getting a basic syntax error. The minimal help for `REGEXEXTRACT` shows that the regexp must be enclosed in double quotes. Your second expression works correctly then:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(E13,"\[(.*?)\]")
```

Answer (score 2):

SPLIT by the space:

```
=SPLIT(E13," ")
```

REGEX:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(E13,"(\S+)\s+\[(\d+)\]")
```

Comment: How can you regexextract for ALL occurrences of a match per row? It seems to only return first match

Comment: @Growler Answered your question.