# Unable to apply regex within vba IE

Tags: regex, vba, excel, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script using vba in combination with IE to parse the contact information from a webpage applying ***regex*** on it. I searched a lot but could not find any example that can satiate my requirement. The `pattern` may not be ideal to find the `phone` number but the main concern here is how I can use the `pattern` within vba IE.

Once again: my intention here is to parse the phone number `661-421-5861` from that webpage applying `regex` within vba IE.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub FetchItems()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.nafe.com/bakersfield-nafe-network"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim rxp As New RegExp, email As Object, Row&

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With

    With rxp
        .Pattern = "(?<=Phone:)\s*?.*?([^\s]+)"
        Set email = .Execute(HTML.body.innerText) 'I'm getting here an error
        If email.Count > 0 Then
            Row = Row + 1: Cells(Row, 1) = email.Item(0)
        End If
    End With
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

When I execute the above script I encounter an error ***method "Execute" of object "IRegExp2" failed*** when it hits the line containing `Set email = .Execute(HTML.body.innerText)`. How can I make it a go successfully?

Comment: Later, you will also get an error related to your regex as VBA regex does not support lookbehinds. Also, that page does not seem to contain `Contact:` string. Maybe you should log in first.

Comment: It is nice to hear from you @Wiktor Stribiżew. This is also a new information to me. The pattern may not be accurate. However, all i wish to know is how to apply it within vba IE.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed that wrongly used `Contact:` within the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that lookbehinds are not supported by VBA regex. Here, you probably want to capture any digit followed with any amount of digits and hyphens after `Phone:`.

You need to re-define the pattern as

```
rxp.Pattern = "Phone:\s*(\d[-\d]+)"
```

Then, you need to grab the first match and access its `.SubMatches(0)`:

```
Set email = .Execute(HTML.body.innerText)
If email.Count > 0 Then
    Cells(Row+1, 1) = email.Item(0).SubMatches(0)
 End If
```

See the [regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/YEmqbv/2). The green-highlighted part of sting is what `.SubMatches(0)` holds.

**Pattern details**

- `Phone:` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d[-\d]+)` - Capturing group 1: a digit, followed with 1+ (due to `+`, you may replace with `*` to match zero or more) digits or/and hyphens.

Comment: You made my day @Wiktor Stribiżew. Thankssss a lot.

Comment: A slight little question on this `[-\d]+` portion @Wiktor Stribiżew. What confuses me is `followed with 1+ digits or/and hyphens`. As I'm a beginner, I knew so far `[-\d]+` means `followed with 1+ digits or hyphens`. Mind the `or` only.  So why it would be `and` as well? A oneliner clarification in comment will suffice. Thanks in advance for taking a look into it.

Comment: @Topto Elements of a *positive* character class are ORed. [`[\d-]+` matches](https://regex101.com/r/FdDs8q/1) 1 or more chars that are either digits or hyphens, it matches `-------------`, `-2-3-5-6-87-9`, or `1223445678988`. Elements of the *negative* character class are ANDed, [`[^\d-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/FdDs8q/2) matches 1 or more chars that are not digits *AND* not hyphens.

Comment: Nothing clearer. It's really difficult to sort things out all alone. Much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quicker way using xmlhttp object

```
Sub FetchItems()
   Dim URL As String, strBody As String
   Dim intS As Long, intE As Long

    URL = "https://www.nafe.com/bakersfield-nafe-network"

    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", URL, False
    xml.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xml.responseText

    strBody = html.body.innerHTML

    intS = InStr(1, strBody, "Phone:", vbTextCompare) + Len("Phone:")
    intE = InStr(intS, strBody, "<", vbTextCompare)

    MsgBox Mid(strBody, intS, intE - intS)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Santosh, for your answer. This is faster but this is not what I sought solution for. Provided plus one.

Comment: @Topto I know but definitely would be useful for other readers :-)