# Extract inside of first square brackets

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

I know there are a few similar questions, but they did not help me, perhaps due to my lack of understanding the basics of string manipulation.

I have a piece of string that I want to extract the inside of its first square brackets.

```
x <- "cons/mod2/det[4]/rost2/rost_act[2]/Q2w5"
```

I have looked all over the internet to assemble the following code but it gives me inside of 2nd brackets

```
sub(".*\\[(.*)\\].*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
```

The code returns **2**. I expect to get **4**.

Would appreciate if someone points out the missing piece.

---- update ----

Replacing `.*` to `.*?` in the first two instances worked, but do not know how. I leave the question open for someone who can provide why this works:

```
sub(".*?\\[(.*?)\\].*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: You can subset the 1st value after using the accepted answer from here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets

Comment: `sub(".*\\[(.*?)\\].*", "\\1", x) ` seems to work as per link @RonakShah suggests.

Comment: Thanks @zacdav, that partially helped. I changed the second `.*` to `.*?` which worked, but don't know how. Thanks Ronak for reference but I couldn't get help there

Comment: @msd `\[(\d)(?:.*)` this matches the first '4'

Comment: `.*?` works because it is a lazy `*`. That is, you match 0 to N times and you preffer the shortest possible match (as opposed to regular `*` that preffers the longest possible match)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
sub("^[^\\]]*\\[(\\d+)\\].*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "4"
```

The original problem is that `.*` matches as much as possible of anything before it matches `[`. Your solution was `*?` which is lazy version of `*` (non-greedy, reluctant) matches as little as it can.

Completely valid, another alternative I used is `[^\\]]*`: which translates into match anything that is not `]`.

Answer (score 0):

### stringr

You can solve this with base R, but I usually prefer the functions from the `stringr`-package when handeling such 'problems'.

```
x <- "cons/mod2/det[4]/rost2/rost_act[2]/Q2w5"
```

If you want only the first string between brackets, use `str_extract`:

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])")
# [1] "4"
```

If you want all the strings between brackets, use `str_extract_all`:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])")
# [[1]]
# [1] "4" "2"
```