# How can I get the value from a string that has the values inside a square bracket []?

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string that comes to me like this: "[value1][value2]"

How can I get the values that are inside the square brackets?
NOTE: if the string is like this "[][value2]" the first bracket that has a space must return a "" to me...

I have been trying a lot of regex and split but none workd.

this is the last I tried:

```
var pattern = /[([^]]*)]/g; 
var res = pattern.exec(datos[0].title);
```

Another one I tried is:

```
var res = datos[0].title.match(/^.*?[([^]]*)].*?[([^]]*)]/gm);
```

but none do what I need...

I'm trying to find a way "that does it all" a regex that gets anything inside the Square brackets (even white spaces)

Comment: What do you know about the values in the brackets? If you know that they won't contain square brackets, you could just use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and then trim off the closing bracket.

Comment: Well Jeff, I have seen many regex that helps, but theyreturn the bracket, this is the last I tried:

var pattern = /\[([^\]]*)]/g;
var res = pattern.exec(datos[0].title);

Another one I tried is:
var res = datos[0].title.match(/^.*?\[([^\]]*)\].*?\[([^\]]*)\]/gm);

but none do what I need...

Comment: Put it on the post. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

Comment: Abana, I don't know why it is relevant to post code that I've tested and does not do what It is required, but updated my post. I'm trying to find a way "that does it all" a regex that gets anything inside the Square brackets (even white spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HarryCutts stated, you don't need regex:

```js
var x = "[value1][value2]";
console.log( x.slice(1,-1).split('][') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex and the brute force way to extract the contents.

```js
var regex = /\[(.*?)\]/g;

var value = "[value1][value2][]";

var matches = value.match(regex);

var matchedValues = matches.map(match => {
 return match.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
}).join(" ");

console.log(matchedValues.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```js
var str = "['value1']['value2']";
var value1 = str.split("]")[0].split("[")[1];
var value2 = str.split("]")[1].split("[")[1];
console.log(str);
console.log(value1);
console.log(value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily expand it for more values.

```js
const string = "[value1][value2]";

const removeBrackets = (stringWithBrackets) => {
  return stringWithBrackets.split("][").map(s => s = s.replace(/\[*\]*/g, ""));
};

const [value1, value2] = removeBrackets(string);

console.log(value1, value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getItems = (fullItemsString) => {
    let items = fullItemsString.replace(/\[/g, "").split("]");
    items.pop()

    return items;
}
```

Using:

```
let items = getItems("[2][][34][1]");
```

result: [ '2', '', '34', '1' ]