# regex select after and between brackets but exclude them from captured group

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex: `((.+?(?=[(]))([(].+?[)]))` and a string template: `"string(100)"`. from that i capture 3 groups. first is `"string(100)"` 2nd, is `"string"` and third is `"(100)"`. But i want to exclude brackets from third group, so i only have `"100"`. I have seen all other similar posts, but couldn't succeed to adapt them to my problem.

I apologize for writing almost duplicate post, I just don't have much time to solve it myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `((.*?)[(](.*?)[)])`. I.e. `/((.*?)\((.*?)\))/`. Or even ``/(.*?)\((.*?)\)/``, the match is in Group 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

Answer (score 0):

just match the parenthesis literally and create a group containing only what is inside the parenthesis:

That's one way to solve it:

```
((.+?(?=[(]))\((.+?)\))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is probably way more complicated than what it needs to be. This minimalistic RegEx can probably solve your problem:

```
(.*)\((.*)\)
```

It matches anything that has a pair of brackets. The whole match can be usually used as a capturing group in all languages/frameworks. The two explicit capturing groups are around everything before the brackets and everything inside. (By "Everything" I mean all characters other than newlines.)

Here's an interactive in-depth explanation and some examples: https://regex101.com/r/OgshEn/1

Answer (score 0):

This regex '/(\w+)((\d+))/' achieves the desired result. Please refer to following javascript result.

```
let matches = "string(100)".match(/(\w+)\((\d+)\)/);
console.log(matches[0]);
console.log(matches[1]);
console.log(matches[2]);
```