# Splitting a string in C# to extract values in parentheses and keep them

Tags: c#, .net

I need to split a string to extract the parentheses and data in a string array using a Regex and keep the parentheses as well.

Extract from

```
1-2-3(0)(1)
```

To

```
(0)
(1)
```

I constructed this Regex, but can't make it work.

```
String phrase= "123(0)(1)"
String[] results = Regex.Split(phrase,"\\r+(?:\\(.*\\))");
```

Comment: `\r` matches a carriage return. Should be `\d`.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(input, @"\([^\)]+\)")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)  Just substitute the square brackets for your parentheses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets

Comment: `Regex.Matches(input, @"\((.*?)\)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex.Matches method instead

```
        string phrase = "123(0)(1)";
        string[] results = Regex.Matches(phrase, @"\(.*?\)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is what I was after. It works perfectly. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using substring method if those two in parenthesis will always be together.

```
phrase = phrase.Substring(phrase.FirstIndexOf("("));
```

Might have to put -1 after.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the numbers in parentheses using `(\(\d\))` pattern.

https://regex101.com/r/chjyLN/1

E.g.

```
var input = "1-2-3(0)(1)";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(\(\d\))");

var matches = pattern.Matches(input);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
  foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works as well. Tnx.