# How to extract string between parentheses that match substring?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract string between parentheses() that match certain substring.

I've been able to extract the string between () already, but couldn't fit in the substring requirement.

Reference: [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

```py
links = re.findall(r'\(([^)]+)\)', page_content)
```

My code only extract the entire string between (), where do I insert the `substring` inside regex?

Sample input:

```html
(XYZ) | **Birthdate**: Dec 10, 1983; - **Social Media**: [Daum Cafe](http://cafe.daum.net/swedjs), [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/skslzowk/), [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/sdiwoel)
```

The output should only be the link for facebook: `https://www.facebook.com/sdiwoel`

Comment: A sample input with matches and non-matches, the substring, and expected output would be very helpful...

Comment: Why should there only be one link? Are you targeting Facebook links explicitly? If there were two Facebook links then should both of them get matched?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to define explicitely. If it's about Facebook as you wrote, perhaps simply

```
re.findall(r'\(([^)]+www\.facebook[^)]+)\)', page_content)
# ['https://www.facebook.com/sdiwoel']
```

could help.