# Replace string values of column if contained in parentheses

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following dataframe as an example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'type':['fruit-of the-loom (sometimes-never)', 'yes', 'ok (not-possible) I will try', 'vegetable', 'poultry', 'poultry'],
                 'item':['apple', 'orange', 'spinach', 'potato', 'chicken', 'turkey']})
```

I found many posts of people wanting to remove parentheses from strings or similar situations, but in my case I would like to retain the string exactly as is, except I would like to remove the `hyphen` that is inside the parenthesis of the string.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could achieve this?

`str.split()` would take care of the hyphen if it was leading and `str.rsplit()` if it was trailing. I can't think of a way to engage this.

in this case the ideal outcome for the values in this hypothetical column would be:

```
'fruit-of the-loom (sometimes never)',
'yes', 
'ok (not possible) I will try', 
'vegetable', 
'poultry', 
'poultry'`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a pattern looking for what is between parenthesis, and the replace parameter could be a lambda using `replace` on the matching object:

```
print (test['type'].str.replace(pat='\((.*?)\)', 
                                repl=lambda x: x.group(0).replace('-',' ')))
0    fruit-of the-loom (sometimes never)
1                                    yes
2           ok (not possible) I will try
3                              vegetable
4                                poultry
5                                poultry
Name: type, dtype: object
```

Explanation of what is in `pat=` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403159/9274732)

Answer (score 1):

```
test.type = (test.type.str.extract('(.*?\(.*?)-(.*?\))(.*)')
             .sum(1)
             .combine_first(test.type))
```

**Explanation:**

- Extract regex groups of `beginning until parenthesis and then hyphen` and `after hyphen until parenthesis and then optional additional stuff`
- Concatenate them together again with `sum`
- Where, `NaN`, use the values from the original (`combine_first`)

This way the hyphen is dropped, not replaced by a space. If you need a space you could use `apply` instead of sum:

```
test.type = (test.type.str.extract('(.*?\(.*?)-(.*?\))(.*)')
             .apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
             .combine_first(test.type))
```

Either way, this won't work for more than one set of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I should have taken a little longer to think about this one.

This is the solution I came up with"

count parenthesis, replace what is within proper count

```
def inside_parens(string):
    parens_count = 0
    return_string = ""
    for a in string:
        if a == "(":
            parens_count += 1
        elif a == ")":
            parens_count -= 1
        if parens_count > 0:
            return_string += a.replace('-', ' ')
        else:
            return_string += a
    return return_string


    return return_string
```

Once this is done apply it to the intended column:

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].apply(inside_parens)
```

If you want to generalize the function you can actually just pass what you want to replace and make it more versatile.