# Extracting number within two square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets) which relevant for me, but I have one additional condition to add and I don't know how to approach that.

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Right now this code will extract everything inside the square brackets, but I wish to extract only numbers.

Assuming I have the following expression `[+₪7.00]`, I wish to extract only `7.00` or `7`.

How can I extract only number from square brackets using regular expression?

Edit:

This is what I tried so far:

```
\[([^\d])\]
```

`[^\d]` suppose to extract only numbers from string, but that doesn't work here.

Also it will give me `700` instead of `7` because of the dot in `7.00`

**EDIT:**

```
//Add Addons & Prices
if($slug == "addon"){
    $temp = explode(',', $value);
    $group = [];
    foreach($temp as $t){
        echo $t;
        $regex = "/\[[^][\d]*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^][]*])/";
        $price = 0;
        $str = $t;
        if (preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches)) {
            foreach ($matches[0] as $match => $m) {
                $price = $m;
             }
        }
        echo $price;
        echo '<br/>';
        $g = [
            'name' => $t,
            'values' => [
                [
                    'id' => 0,
                    'name' => $t,
                    'price' => $price
                ]
            ]
        ];
        array_push($group, $g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your current regex to see what the issue is? Also, it is not clear what you want to do with `[+7.00 and 89]` cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Shouldn't expect any case like that, only single number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extracrt a single number from in between square brackets, you can use

```php
\[[^][\d]*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^][]*])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tTVo3L/1). *Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^][\d]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and digits
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the current overall match memory buffer
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `(?=[^][]*])` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/fnF7G):

```php
$re = '/\[[^][\d]*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^][]*])/';
$str = 'I have the following expression [+₪7.00], I wish to extract only 7.00 or 7.';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches[0]);
}
// => Array( [0] => 7.00 )
```

**Just in case you have multiple numbers to extract...**

Then, you can use

```php
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^][\d]*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^][]*])
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tTVo3L/2). `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)` matches the end of the previous successful match or a `[` char.

Comment: I have another issue with that, I have Hebrew in my string, and the regex doesn't work with Hebrew, what could cause that? This is my string: 
`בולגרית [+₪7.00]`  - Debug result: `8362` instead of `7.00`

Comment: @ExCluSiv3 Could you please check [this demo](https://3v4l.org/AWhq7)? I do not see any issue.

Comment: That's weird, when I extract value from an array using foreach loop (`בולגרית [+₪7.00]`) I get `8362`, but when using the same string (instead of getting it out of the array) I get the correct value (`7.00`).

I can't understand why is this happening, got any idea?

Comment: @ExCluSiv3 `$re = '/\[[^][\d]*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=[^][]*])/u';`

Comment: I understand why this happens, the currency symbol `₪` equals to `8362` hex code, how can I filter him?

Comment: @ExCluSiv3 You probably need to use `html_entity_decode($str)` instead, to convert entities to literal characters.