# Get the characters in the separator

Tags: typescript

I have a string like this: "[A] [B] this is my [C] string".
How can I take the characters in [] and replace it with others (add and remove [])

Comment: Is it an array or just a string?

Comment: that's string I want reform it

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? You want to replace A, B and C with what (what is the meaning of 'replace it with others)? Please put a example input and output if possible

Comment: Here's a regex that matches what you want to match. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

Comment: Let me example: "[A][B] this is my string [C]" ABC in that string will match 123, and I want the output string: "12 this is my string3"

Comment: yes, I have also thought of regex. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for that info.  So you want the order of the match?  Like replace the first match with `1`?  Or replace the `[A]` match with `1` regardless of order?  This is one possible solution `const replaced = s.replaceAll(/\[(.*?)\]/g, (withBrackets, innerText, position) => { /* return something */ })` but it doesn't get the order of the match in the callback.  `position` is the index of the character in the string.

Comment: I get it from array, example I have string array is ["A", "B", "C"] and number array [1, 2, 3] I just want replace them in order

Comment: I think I've answered correctly?  Can you please update your question to explain the requirements so that others can see what you want without reading through the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to approach this.  To some extend it depends on what your replacement function is and what information it needs.  I believe this first one is what you want.  It ignores the contents of the matched targets `A`, `B`, `C` entirely and instead replaces with a pre-defined value based on the order of the brackets.

I am using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with the regex explained in the linked question:

- [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403159/10431574)

You could remove the parentheses in the regex which denote the capture group since we aren't actually using the captured text.

```js
const replacements = [1, 2, 3];

const input = "[A] [B] this is my [C] string";

const output = replacements.reduce( 
  (string, replacement) => string.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/, replacement), 
  input
 );
 
 console.log(output);
```

This next version assumes that the output is based on the text inside the brackets rather than the order or appearance.  Therefore `[A]` is replaced with `1` regardless of the order that the placeholders appear in the string.

I am using [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).  The callback function gets three arguments which I have tried to give descriptive names.  `withBrackets` is the full match like `"[A]"`, `innerText` is the text inside the brackets `"A"`, and `position` is the index in the string where the match begins.

```js
const input = "[A] [B] this is my [C] string";

// with TS: const replacementFunction = (text: string): string => {
const replacementFunction = (text) => {
  return text === "A" ? 1 : text === "B" ? 2 : 3
}

// no TS needed
const replaced = input.replaceAll(/\[(.*?)\]/g, (withBrackets, innerText, position) => {
  // do something with the match
  return replacementFunction(innerText);
});

console.log(replaced)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string, then do it this way:

```
let myString = "[A] [B] this is my [C] string";

// find the left string and replace it with the right
const replaced1 = myString.replace("[C]", "[E]");

console.log(replaced1);
```