# How to match everything that is between brackets AND exactly before a specific string using Regex?

Tags: regex

I have this text, which is used for pagination and comes as a string:

```
[https://example.com/page2]; rel="prev", [https://example.com/page4]; rel="next", [https://example.com/page1]; rel="first", [https://example.com/page7]; rel="last"
```

I need to extract from this string the following sub-string, that is the next link on the pagination, as informed in the "rel" attribute right after it:

```
https://example.com/page4
```

What I tried to do to achieve this is to match everything exactly before this text: `; rel="next"`, that is between brackets.
So I came up with this regular expression:

```regex
(\[(.*?)\]); rel="next"
```

The problem here is that it considers the closing bracket that is right before `; rel="next"`, but for the opening bracket it gets the first one, which means the result is as follows:

```
https://example.com/page2]; rel="prev", [https://example.com/page4
```

I have to look for `; rel="next"` because the order of the elements can't be trusted, they might come sorted differently or some of them might not come at all.

Is there a way to indicate in my regex the correct opening bracket? or maybe there is a better way to get the same result?

Comment: Match the [*closest* square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62129083/3832970). In that post, you will find the right escaping for your regex flavor, I believe.

Comment: If Lookbehinds are supported, use `(?<=rel="next", )\[[^]]*\]`. Otherwise, use a capturing group: `rel="next", (\[[^]]*\])`.