# How to extract string between square brackets when string also contains square brackets

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string closed to square brackets:

`[[oneOne1, oneOne2], oneTwo, oneThree]`

I neet to extract substing that is closed to square brackets and get

`[oneOne1, oneOne2], oneTwo, oneThree`

I've tried to use regex. But the the hard part is that my substring also stores `[` and `]`.

This is a string value of some variable that I receive. And it could be more than one occurrence in the string. I mean that string could also look like:

`[[oneOne1, oneOne2], oneTwo, oneThree][[twoOne1, twoOne2], twoTwo, twoThree][[threeOne1, threeOne2], threeTwo, threeThree]`

and I should extract all occurances:

`[oneOne1, oneOne2], oneTwo, oneThree`

`[twoOne1, twoOne2], twoTwo, twoThree`

`[threeOne1, threeOne2], threeTwo, threeThree`

There is a lot of such questions here but I didn't find solution for my case with internal `[]`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets) I found solution for `PHP PCRE`, but I can't convert it to java 8.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no more than two levels of nested square brackets:

```
(?<=\[)(?:[^\[\]]+|\[[^\[\]]+\])+
```

see [here](https://regex101.com/r/cOSytP/1) for the online demo.

---

- `(?<=)`: Positive lookbehind

  - `\[`: Matches `[`.
- `(?:)`: Non capturing group.

  - `[^\[\]]+`: Matches any character other than `[` or `]`, between one and unlimited times, as much as possible.
  - `|`: Or.
  - `\[[^\[\]]+\]`: Matches `[`, matches any character other than `[` or `]`, between one and unlimited times, matches `]`.
- `+`: Matches the preceding group between one and unlimited times, as much as possible.