# Replace date in string with date format

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace patterns of date in string as date, so from this input:

```
log_{yyyy-MM} foo {HH}.txt
```

I should get:

```
log_2020-06 foo 11.txt
```

I created something like this:

```cs
public static string ReplaceDate(string input)
{
    var r = new Regex(@"\{(.*?)\}");
    var dateFormat = r.Match(input).Groups[1].Value; //Get the first matching group
    return r.Replace(input,DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat));
}
```

And with this input:

```
log_{yyyy-MM} foo.txt
```

My code returns (which is OK):

```
log_2022-06 foo.txt
```

but with this input:

```
log_{yyyy-MM} foo {HH}.txt
```

I get wrong output:

```
log_2022-06 foo 2022-06.txt
```

Any ideas how can I make it working with many groups?

Answer (score 1):

Call the [`Regex.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) overload that allows you to pass a `MatchEvaluator` function:

```
return r.Replace( input, (match) => DateTime.Now.ToString( match.Groups[1].Value ) );
```

This way you can replace each date format pattern individually.

Answer (score 0):

So the main idea is get every `{group}` and replace it with the parameters of:
[Microsoft Date Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). But in any case I would suggest take consideration of your input, there are a lot of things can be wrong here: [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

```
string input = "log_{yyyy-MM} foo {HH}.txt";
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

string[] results = Regex.Matches(input,@"\{.*?\}" ).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray(); 


foreach(string result in results) {
    input = input.Replace(result,now.ToString(result));
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cYdJtW

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to exactly use Regex then there are simple -and probably more effective- ways to do what you try.

As an example -I couldn't check code for typos as i write what i remember- :

```
//Method to Trying Parse the given string to DateTime.
public static DateTime TryParseStrToDate (string DateString)
{
  var date = new DateTime();
            
  bool b = DateTime.TryParse(DateString, date);
            
  return date;
}
            
/// To create a file name with your special formatting needs
public static string CreateLogFileName(DateTime TheDate, bool IncludeHour)
{
    if(TheDate == new DateTime())
    { 
       throw new ArgumentNullException("Date Should be valid"); 
    }
    
return $"log_{TheDate.Year}-{TheDate.Month} foo {IncludeHour?TheDate.Hour : string.Empty}.txt";
}

...//Method Codes to Save the log file
```