# How can i get the gpu model name from inside the brackets?

Tags: windows, powershell, html-table

i want to get just the model name of the gpu by searching for the "$deviceid".

So this is what i have at the moment:

```
Install-Module PSParseHtml

$deviceid = "0x1f02"
$Url = 'https://envytools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hw/pciid.html#gpu'
$AllTables = ConvertFrom-HtmlTable -Url $Url
$AllTables | Where-Object {$_."device id" -match $deviceid}
```

My output is this:

```
device id product                        
--------- -------                        
0x1f02    TU106 [GeForce RTX 2070]       
0x1f07    TU106 [GeForce RTX 2070]       
0x1f08    TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060]       
0x1f10    TU106 [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile]
0x1f11    TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile]
0x1f50    TU106 [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile]
0x1f51    TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile]
```

How can i get now as output only the gpu model name "**GeForce RTX 2070**" with the matching device id "**0x1f02**"

Thank you

Comment: See the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has two distinct aspects:

- A question that is *specific* to the [`PSParseHTML`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSParseHTML/) module's `ConvertFrom-HtmlTable` cmdlet:

  - `ConvertFrom-HtmlTable`, outputs *whole arrays* in your case, so that `$AllTables` is in effect a *nested* array, whereas you want to filter by the *individual elements* of those nested arrays.
  - To force these nested arrays to be *enumerated*, so that [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) can act on *individual objects*, as usual, you can simply pipe to [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output):

    ```bash
    # Thanks to Write-Output, outputs *only* the object (table row)
    # with device ID $deviceID. 
    # Note the use of -eq instead of -match
    # (-match is only needed for regex matching).
    $AllTables | 
      Write-Output |  # Enumerate arrays
      Where-Object { $_.'device id' -eq $deviceid }
    ```
- A *general* question about how to select and transform properties from given input objects - see below.

---

In order to select a subset of properties and/or transform the values of the properties of input objects, use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object). In order to transform property values, use it with [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties). The result will be `[pscustomobject]` instances that have the desired properties and values.

```bash
$sampleInput = [pscustomobject] @{
  'device id' = '0x1f02'
  product = 'TU106 [GeForce RTX 2070]'
}

# Use a calculated property to select and transform the 'product' value,
# and select the 'device id' property as-is.
$sampleInput |
  Select-Object @{
      Name='product';
      Expression={ ($_.product -split '[][]')[1] }
    }, 
    'device id'
```

The [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator is used to split each product name by `[` and `]`; the 2nd element (index `1`) of the resulting array contains the substring of interest. Alternatively, you could use the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator: `$_.product -replace '^.+\[(.+?)\]$', '$1'`

Output:

```
product          device id
-------          ---------
GeForce RTX 2070 0x1f02
```

Note: If you don't actually need to construct *new objects* and are simply looking for the *formatted display* shown above, you can substitute [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) for `Select-Object`; however, note that such output is then truly only usable for *display* purposes.