# How do I get the match data for all occurrences of a Ruby regular expression in a string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need the `MatchData` for each occurrence of a regular expression in a string. This is different than the scan method suggested in [Match All Occurrences of a Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80357/ruby-match-all-occurrences-of-a-regex), since that only gives me an array of strings (I need the full MatchData, to get begin and end information, etc).

```
input = "abc12def34ghijklmno567pqrs"
numbers = /\d+/

numbers.match input # #<MatchData "12"> (only the first match)
input.scan numbers  # ["12", "34", "567"] (all matches, but only the strings)
```

I suspect there is some method that I've overlooked. Suggestions?

Comment: I want the begin and end positions for each match. But that is irrelevant to my question. MatchData exists for a reason, doesn't it? If I can get it for the first match, it follows that it would be useful for all matches.

Comment: Ok, I want more than one thing, in a convenient package, for each match.

Comment: You have the convenient package, as you name it, in the solution I gave below (from which you can get begin, end or whatever match data you need as you wish) . Or is it anything else that you are looking for?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You want

```
"abc12def34ghijklmno567pqrs".to_enum(:scan, /\d+/).map { Regexp.last_match }
```

which gives you

```
[#<MatchData "12">, #<MatchData "34">, #<MatchData "567">]
```

The "trick" is, as you see, to build an enumerator in order to get each `last_match`.

Comment: This should be on apidock.com or similar. You saved me from at least 10 new grey hairs :)

Comment: It's unbelievable that there isn't a built-in method for this, that we have to resort to a hack like this.

Answer (score 9):

My current solution is to add an `each_match` method to Regexp:

```
class Regexp
  def each_match(str)
    start = 0
    while matchdata = self.match(str, start)
      yield matchdata
      start = matchdata.end(0)
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can do:

```
numbers.each_match input do |match|
  puts "Found #{match[0]} at #{match.begin(0)} until #{match.end(0)}"
end
```

Tell me there is a better way.

Comment: this should actually be appended to your original question, unless you intend it to be the answer.

Comment: Also, `while matchdata = self.match(str, start)` is considered a very hard to maintain construct because it is difficult to know if this is an error or intentional.

Comment: Why should it be appended to the question? It's an answer. I'm just hoping there is a better answer, which is why I didn't just accept my own. If a better answer isn't found, then eventually I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Please reread what I wrote. Append it *UNLESS* you intend it to be the answer. Stack Overflow prefers that information added by the original poster be appended to your original question, however answers provided by the OP can be added as an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: It's clean, it's easy to read and it works just fine. You could write is a an [enumerator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43167606/6419007) if you wish. I didn't notice your answer before writing mine. They're basically the same.

Answer (score 9):

I’ll put it here to make the code available via a search:

```rb
input = "abc12def34ghijklmno567pqrs"
numbers = /\d+/
input.gsub(numbers) { |m| p $~ }
```

The result is as requested:

```
⇒ #<MatchData "12">
⇒ #<MatchData "34">
⇒ #<MatchData "567">
```

See "[input.gsub(numbers) { |m| p $~ } Matching data in Ruby for all occurrences in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632395/input-gsubnumbers-m-p-matching-data-in-ruby-for-all-occurrences-in-a/27632610#27632610)" for more information.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, works perfectly, especially as I wanted to actually use `gsub` anyway.

Comment: Rather than do this, use `scan` if all you intend to do is get the MatchData. It communicates intention clearer.

Comment: @justin, the question *explicitly* says that `scan` does not return MatchData's, but just an array of matched strings.

Comment: @DeFazer it's been a while,  but iirc, `$~` is the `MatchData` for the last match,  which would make my comment relevant still

Comment: @Justin, technically, you are right. `$~` is, indeed, the `MatchData` for the last match. However, there is a little trick - since `gsub` sets `$~` multiple times per iteration, on each iteration `{ |m| p $~ }` returns different `MatchData`'s.
Besides, I'm not sure I understand how `scan` can be useful in getting `MatchData`'s. Can you explain this part, please?

Comment: @DeFazer as a drop in replacement for gsub here. http://ideone.com/tRfi12

Comment: @Justin oh! I see. Thanks, now I get what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the amazing [StringScanner](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html) class included in Ruby's standard library:

```
require 'strscan'

s = StringScanner.new('abc12def34ghijklmno567pqrs')

while s.skip_until(/\d+/)
  num, offset = s.matched.to_i, [s.pos - s.matched_size, s.pos - 1]

  # ..
end
```

No, it doesn't give you the MatchData objects, but it does give you an index-based interface into the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = "abc12def34ghijklmno567pqrs"
n = Regexp.new("\\d+")
[n.match(input)].tap { |a| a << n.match(input,a.last().end(0)+1) until a.last().nil? }[0..-2]

=> [#<MatchData "12">, #<MatchData "34">, #<MatchData "567">]
```