# Extract using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

I'm new to Ruby, Regex and Stackoverflow. xD Here's my problem:

I want to use regex to extract phrases consisting of consecutive words with standard ASCII characters apart from the others in Vietnamese texts.

In another word, phrases with **\w** characters only, for example:

> Mình rất thích con Sharp này (mặc dù chưa xài bao h nhưng chỉ nghe các
>   pác nói mình đã thấy phê lòi mắt rồi). Các bạn cho mình hỏi 1 câu (các
>   bạn đừng chê mình ngu nhé tội nghiệp mình) : cái máy này đem sang Anh
>   dùng mạng Vodafone là dùng vô tư ah`? Nếu dùng được bên Anh mà không
>   phải chọc ngoáy j thì mình mua một cái

Don't care about its meaning, what I want to achieve is an array of hashes containing the results with 2 pairs: **value => *the value of extracted phrases*, starting_position => *the position of the first character***.

According to the example about, it should be like this:
[{:value=>"con Sharp", :starting_position => 16}, {:value=>"bao h", :starting_position => blah blah}...]

This means that all words containing **\W** characters, such as "mình", "rất", "thích", etc. are rejected.

Trying above example with this regex on **rubular.com** for **Ruby 1.9.2**:

> **\b[\w|\s]+\b**

I nearly got my desired phrases (except space-only ones), but it seems not working on my Ruby, which is also 1.9.2p290, using Win 7 64-bit.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to rubular, it looks like `\w`  matches all ascii letters and numbers (and underscored), but `\b` is working well for all Unicode letters. That is a little confusing.

What you want, however, are all sequences of ASCII words. This should match them:

```
/\b[a-z]+\b(?:\s+[a-z]+)*\b/i
```

Working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/1iewl7MpJe

A quick explanation:

- `\b[a-z]+\b` - first ASCII word.
- `(?:\s+[a-z]+)` - any number of spaces and words - at least one space and one letter each time.
- `\b` - to assure the last word doesn't end in the middle of another word, like `n` in `"con Sharp này"`.

I'm not sure about getting an hash, but you can get all [`MatchData`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html)s, similar to:
[How do I get the match data for all occurrences of a Ruby regular expression in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804557/how-do-i-get-the-match-data-for-all-occurrences-of-a-ruby-regular-expression-in)

```
s = "hello !@# world how a9e you"
r = /\b[a-z]+\b(?:\s+[a-z]+)*\b/i

matches = s.to_enum(:scan, r).map { Regexp.last_match }
           .map {|match| [match.to_s(), match.begin(0)]}
puts matches
```

Here's an example on ideone: http://ideone.com/YRZE5

Comment: Looks like `\b\w+\b(?:\s+\w+)*\b` would work as well. I'm not sure why I thought \w does match all Unicode letters... Anyway, I'll be checking some documentations. I can't really find it in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much. By the way, how can I get result array as described above using Ruby? I tried **scan** and **match** but did not know how to deal with them?

Comment: @ThiemNguyen - Thanks! I've added an example for getting the data you need. I don't really know Ruby aside from answering Stack Overflow questions, so you can probably do better then me `:P`

Comment: I managed to extract them using Ruby and your regex. Thanks in advance. xD