# Search for all occurrences of a letter in a string with offsets

Tags: ruby

I have a string as follows:

```
--d--d-d---d--
```

I want to find all occurrences of 'd' in this string with their offsets.

However, doing the following only gives me back the first result:

```
irb(main):001:0> m = /d/.match "d--d-d---d"
=> #<MatchData "d">
irb(main):002:0> m.size
=> 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought `match` will match all occurrences of the regex in the string.

Answer (score 0):

To get the offset, you can use a loop like this:

```
s = '--d--d-d---d--'
offset = 0
while md = /d/.match(s,offset)
  p md.offset(0)[1]          
  # MatchDate#offset Returns a two-element array 
  # containing the beginning and ending offsets 
  offset = md.offset(0)[1]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why it does not contain all the matches, which according to the core doc (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/MatchData.html) sounds like it should be the case, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @mydoghasworms `#match` only runs the regexp once. `MatchData` contains offsets for the whole match and for each capture group.

Comment: Why loop over `match` & matchdata when `index` returns the desired offsets directly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I am looking for is in fact on this question: [How do I get the match data for all occurrences of a Ruby regular expression in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804557/how-do-i-get-the-match-data-for-all-occurrences-of-a-ruby-regular-expression-in)

Like I said, I thought the MatchData result should contain all occurrences of the match. (I got this impression from the Ruby core doc here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/MatchData.html).

So while I still don't understand that part completely, at least the answer above helps me to get to all the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant:

```
str = '--d--d-d---d--'
str.each_char.with_index.select{|el| el[0] == "d"}.map(&:last)
```

Result:

```
[2, 5, 7, 11]
```

Just position of letter started from 0. If you need it to start from 1 use `with_index(1)`, so result will be:

```
[3, 6, 8, 12]
```

Comment: This works nicely when the pattern is a single character but not at all if it's a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

[`Regexp#match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match) only runs the pattern once. `MatchData` can contain multiple matches and thus [multiple offsets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/MatchData.html#method-i-offset). The first one is the entire match, the others are the contents of the capture groups within the regexp. There's nothing in MatchData resulting from multiple applications of the regexp.

[`String#index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-index) produces offsets directly and can be easily used to iterate through the string.

```
s = '--d--d-d---d--'
[].tap{ |offsets| i=-1; while i = s.index('d', i+1); offsets << i; end }
=> [2, 5, 7, 11]
```