# How to find out the starting point for each match in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, hashtag

Say, i have a following string

```
string = "#Sachin is Indian cricketer. #Tendulkar is right hand batsman. #Sachin has been honoured with the Padma Vibhushan award "
```

I want o/p as

```
"#Sachin|0|7;#Tendulkar|29|10;#Sachinn|63|7;"
```

I tried following

```
 new_string = ""
 string.scan(/#\S+/).each{|match| new_string+="#{match}|#{string.index(match)}|#{match.length};"  }
```

which gives me

```
 "#Sachin|0|7;#Tendulkar|29|10;#Sachin|0|7;"
```

So how i will get the starting index of each sub-string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually quite a non-trivial task, and has been discussed quite a bit in other questions on SO. This is the most common solution:

```
string = "#Sachin is Indian cricketer. #Tendulkar is right hand batsman. #Sachin has been honoured with the Padma Vibhushan award "
new_string = string.to_enum(:scan,/#\S+/i).inject(''){|s,m| s + "#{m}|#{$`.size}|#{m.length};"}
```

Comment: +1 and deleted my answer :)  You could make your solution even simpler with inject - string.to_enum(:scan,/#\S+/i).inject('') { |s,m| s + "#{m}|#{$`.size}|#{m.length};" }

Comment: Not sure it helps for the reading, but it was fairly illegible anyway so I've updated :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this thread [How do I get the match data for all occurrences of a Ruby regular expression in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804557/how-do-i-get-the-match-data-for-all-occurrences-of-a-ruby-regular-expression-in) just quick example:

```
string = "#Sachin is Indian cricketer. #Tendulkar is right hand batsman. #Sachin has been honoured with the Padma Vibhushan award "
new_string = ""
string
  .to_enum(:scan, /#\S+/)
  .each do |wrd|
    m = Regexp.last_match
    new_string += "#{wrd}|#{m.offset(0)[0]}|#{wrd.length};"
  end
p new_string
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that uses scan:

```
offset = 0
string.scan(/(#\S*)([^#]*)/).map{|m| v = "#{m[0]}|#{offset}|#{m[0].length};"; offset += m.join.length; v}.join
#=> "#Sachin|0|7;#Tendulkar|29|10;#Sachin|63|7;"
```