# Ruby regular expression matching enumerator with named capture support

Tags: ruby, regex, capture-group

Consider a string like this to extract the time information:

`str = "Sun rises at 6:23 am & sets at 5:45 pm; Moon comes up by 7:20 pm and goes down by 3:45 am"`

I wish to have an enumerator like **scan** but one that can get me the **MatchData** objects instead of arrays as available from scan.

For instance, I can write:

`str.scan( /(?<time>\d:\d{2}) (?<meridiem>am|pm)/ ){ |arr| p arr }`

to get:

`["6:23", "am"]
["5:45", "pm"]
["7:20", "pm"]
["3:45", "am"]`

But, I wonder if there something like this:

`str.match_all( /(?<time>\d:\d{2}) (?<meridiem>am|pm)/ ){ |md| p md }`

to get:

`#<MatchData "6:23 am" time:"6:23" meridiem:"am">
 #<MatchData "5:45 pm" time:"5:45" meridiem:"pm">
 #<MatchData "7:20 pm" time:"7:20" meridiem:"pm">
 #<MatchData "3:45 am" time:"3:45" meridiem:"am">`

Saw an answer in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807722/2602869), but I feel its an inelegant solution. So checking up in case things have changed over the last couple of years since the answer was posted.

Comment: The accepted answer on the question you referred seems short and quite elegant to me. You can implement this `match_all` based on that.

Comment: I agree with @Guilherme, but it's been helpful to me to think about your question, and see the earlier answer.

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question is as elegant as I can think of. If you are not satisfied with even that, then think of a more elegant answer by yourself. Considering your high standards, you should be able to do that by yourself.

Comment: Thanks everyone; probably you are right! I somehow assumed such a `match_all` method should exist, assuming the requirement to be rather common. I must apologise in using the term "inelegant" for the quoted answer; I was just looking for a rather direct method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very identical to the answer you have already seen, but slightly different.

```
str = "Sun rises at 6:23 am & sets at 5:45 pm; Moon comes up by 7:20 pm ..."
str.gsub(/(?<time>\d:\d{2}) (?<meridiem>am|pm)/).map{ Regexp.last_match } 

#=> [#<MatchData "6:23 am" time:"6:23" meridiem:"am">, #<MatchData "5:45 pm" ...
```

Comment: I was thinking about a similar solution, but I didn't know `Regexp.last_match` existed. But somehow catching the MatchData from there seems problematic to me, when thinking about its scope.

Comment: Really wished something like `match_all` existed! Quite unbelievable why it doesn't.