# input.gsub(numbers) { |m| p $~ } Matching data in Ruby for all occurrences in a string

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Answer from [How do I get the match data for all occurrences of a Ruby regular expression in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804557/how-do-i-get-the-match-data-for-all-occurrences-of-a-ruby-regular-expression-in/14662414#14662414):

```rb
input = "abc12def34ghijklmno567pqrs"
numbers = /\d+/
input.gsub(numbers) { |m| p $~ }
```

Result is as requested:

```
⇒ #<MatchData "12">
⇒ #<MatchData "34">
⇒ #<MatchData "567">
```

Would someone break down what the answerer is doing in `input.gsub(numbers) { |m| p $~ }`?

Also, how would I access each of the `MatchData`s?

Comment: did you wanna explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I’m the answerer, I would try to explain.

`$~` is one of [Ruby predefined globals](http://rocket-science.ru/tips/2013/02/26/ruby-predefined-globals/#tilde). It returns **the MatchData from the previous successful pattern match**. It may be accessed using `Regexp.last_match` as well.

As [stated in the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-gsub), `gsub` with block is commonly used to modify string, but here we use the fact it calls the codeblock on every match. Block variable `m` there is a simple string for that match, so whether we need the whole `MatchData` instance, we should use the predefined global `$~`. In the mentioned example we simple print each `MatchData` with `p $~`.

The trick here is that `$~` returns **the last `MatchData`**. So, everything you need is to use `$~` variable despite it’s repulsive look. Or, you might set:

```
my_beauty_name_match_data_var = $~
```

and play with the latter. Hope it helps.

Comment: also, you can use predefined variable `$&` to get the string for match and pass nothing to block(I mean instead of `m`)

Comment: Thank you! That's amazing that you were able to find my question about your code so quickly! Would you link to your explanation here from your answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804557/how-do-i-get-the-match-data-for-all-occurrences-of-a-ruby-regular-expression-in/14662414#14662414)?

Comment: Glad to help. Linked.