# Why does /[<>]/ not return both angle brackets with String#match?

Tags: ruby, regex, character-class

I expect this example to match the two characters `<`and `>`:

```
a = "<1acf457f477b41d4a363e89a1d0a6e57@Open-Xchange>"
a.match /[<>]/
# => #<MatchData "<">
```

It matches only the first character. Why?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: That's what it does, return only the first matched result.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804557/how-do-i-get-the-match-data-for-all-occurrences-of-a-ruby-regular-expression-in

Answer (score 2):

`#match` only returns the first match as you have seen as MatchData,  `#scan` will return all matches.

```
>> a="<1acf457f477b41d4a363e89a1d0a6e57@Open-Xchange>"
=> "<1acf457f477b41d4a363e89a1d0a6e57@Open-Xchange>"
>> a.scan /[<>]/
=> ["<", ">"]
```

Comment: `#scan` won't return MatchDatas though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is there a `scan` -like method that returns matchdata?

Comment: see @jrochkkind comment,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804557/how-do-i-get-the-match-data-for-all-occurrences-of-a-ruby-regular-expression-in   shows a way to get them as match data

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

You are misunderstanding your expression. `/[<>]/` means:

> Match a single character from the character class, which may be either `<` or `>`.

Ruby is correctly giving you exactly what you've asked for in your pattern.

### Solution

If you're expecting the entire string between the two characters, you need a different pattern. For example:

```
"<1acf457f477b41d4a363e89a1d0a6e57@Open-Xchange>".match /<.*?>/
#=> #<MatchData "<1acf457f477b41d4a363e89a1d0a6e57@Open-Xchange>">
```

Alternatively, if you just want to match all the instances of `<` or `>` in your string, then you should use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-scan) with a character class or alternation. In this particular case, the results will be identical either way. For example:

```
"<1acf457f477b41d4a363e89a1d0a6e57@Open-Xchange>".scan /<|>/
#=> ["<", ">"]

"<1acf457f477b41d4a363e89a1d0a6e57@Open-Xchange>".scan /[<>]/
#=> ["<", ">"]
```

Comment: I think he understands the pattern just fine (meaning, it's not The problem here)