# Regexp.last_match - why is it useful?

Tags: ruby, regex

In "**Comprehensive Ruby programming course**' e-book, I faced a chapter, where author (Jordan Hudgens) describes it like:

“The last thing we are going to try is to return all the integer values from the sentence.”

And he does it like this:

```
string = "The quick 12 brown foxes jumped over 10 lazy dogs"
p string.to_enum(:scan, /\d+/).map { Regexp.last_match }
```

And it returns:

```
=> [#<MatchData "3">, #<MatchData "34">, #<MatchData "23">]
```

I wonder why / when, this `Regexp.last_match` might be used or better to say - why this way is not more efficient than:

```
p string.to_enum(:scan, /\d+/).map { |i| p i }
```

This outputs only an array of integers and seems for me as a more efficient way to get those numbers..

Anyone maybe could explain what might was the reasons for author to pick `Regesp.last_match` ?

Comment: What you suggest would be *way* better. Global mutable state is ugly. Using global mutable state *and* relying on an implementation detail? Yuck. It’s possible you should pick a different e-book.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Next thing for me to read is "Global mutable" :) I will delete this post if it will seem as too broad or unanswerable. And about that book - it was, actually, quite nice, just this part was a bit strange...

Comment: @Ryan 1. those return _different_ things, 2. `Regexp.last_match` is _not_ global mutable.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Is this about thread locals or something else? I’m also not sure how returning different things is a problem if the end goal was to get the integer values.

Comment: Also, you could just use `string.scan(/\d+/)`.

Comment: Yes, it’s about thread locals. We have no idea was was the original intent, but this code is used to get an array of `MatchData` instances.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Thread-local is a type of global, and remains as awful as I made it out to be.

Comment: Apparently [this is standard for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804557/how-do-i-get-the-match-data-for-all-occurrences-of-a-ruby-regular-expression-in?lq=1), which is rather horrifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nifty trick (read: hack).

```
string = "The quick 12 brown foxes jumped over 10 lazy dogs"
p string.to_enum(:scan, /\d+/).map { Regexp.last_match }
```

The thing is there is no handy way to `yield` instances of `MatchData` from inside `String#scan`.

```
p string.to_enum(:scan, /\d+/).map { |i| p i }
```

makes not much sense, you probably meant:

```
p string.to_enum(:scan, /\d+/).map(&:itself) # or { |i| i } # or .to_a
```

or even

```
p string.scan(/\d+/)
```

The results *differ*, though; the latter returns *strings*, while the former is a way to return [`MatchData`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/MatchData.html) instances.

Comment: Why would you `.map(&:itself)`?

Comment: @Ryan To make the code to actually execute. `to_enum` returns a lazy enumerator.

Comment: So a long way of saying `.to_a`?

Comment: Yes; I tried to make as few changes to the OP’s code as possible.

Comment: @mudasobwa, thanks. As @Justin wrote under one of your other answers, wouldn't this be somehow different?  `string.to_enum(:scan, /\d+/).map { |m| p $~ }` ? I totally new to this so don't understand what `$~` means... I could ask another question if you will, just don't even know how to ask it :)

Comment: `$~` is an exact (though cryptic) synonym of `Regexp.last_match`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more verbose but possibly cleaner solution if you want an Enumerator of [`MatchData`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/MatchData.html) instances :

```
class String
  def matches(regex)
    position = 0
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      while match = regex.match(self, position)
        yielder << match
        position = match.end(0)
      end
    end
  end
end

string = 'The quick 12 brown foxes jumped over 10 lazy dogs'
p string.matches(/\d+/).to_a
# [#<MatchData "12">, #<MatchData "10">]
p (2**1000000).to_s.matches(/(\d)\1{5}/).first(2)
# [#<MatchData "444444" 1:"4">, #<MatchData "888888" 1:"8">]
```

If you don't want to monkey patch `String`, you could define this method in `Regex` or as a stand-alone method with `string` and `regex` as parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, but my meta skills is about at 0 or -1, so I will better wait for anyone more experienced to judge it :) p.s. Monkey patch means meta programming (overriding software in this case)? :)

Comment: @J.D. : Monkey-patching means opening an existing class and modifying it, e.g. by defining a new method. This code isn't really "meta", and is closer to what you would write in Java or Python.