# Regex - Match all words in parenthesis

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following regular expression that is supposed to match all words that have parenthesis around them (including the parenthesis) but it only matches one case. What am I doing wrong?

```
"(e), (f), and (g)".match(/\(\w+\)/)
=> #<MatchData "(e)">
```

The output should be:

```
=> #<MatchData "(e)", 1: "(f)", 2: "(g)">
```

Comment: Not a Ruby coder, but did you try [`scan()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/80387/1438393) instead?

Comment: Side note, you may want to use the expression [`/\([^)]+\)/`](http://www.rubular.com/r/SkpBW6ghDC) if there is a chance for non-`\w` characters.

Comment: Does Ruby 'match' stop after the first match? Does it take the global flag `//g` ?

Comment: `scan` is what you want, unless you specifically need a `MatchData`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`scan()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan) instead. It returns an array with all the matches. `match()` will only return the first match.

```
"(e), (f), and (g)".scan(/\(\w+\)/)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Totally forgot about `scan()`.