# Deleting between tags and using variables in regex in `gsub`

Tags: ruby, regex

My `@outbound_text` looks something like this:

```
<CREATE-EVENT>\n\t\t\t\t<COLLECTION>PAM</COLLECTION>\n\t\t\t\t<EVENT-TYPE>survey_answer</EVENT-TYPE>\n\t\t\t\t<JSON-STRING>\n\t\t\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\t question1:done,\n\t\t\t\t\t question2:done,\n\t\t\t\t\t question3:done,\n\t\t\t\t\t question4:done,\n\t\t\t\t\t question5:done,\n\t\t\t\t\t question6:done\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t</JSON-STRING>\n\t\t\t</CREATE-EVENT>\n\n\t\t\t\n      <EMAIL>\n        <ADDRESS>bot_client_id</ADDRESS>\n        <SUBJECT>PAM responses for Wednesday October 07</SUBJECT>\n        <BODY>\nHi, there
```

I want to remove everything between `<CREATE-EVENT>` and `</CREATE-EVENT>`.

I tried the following, where `tag` is`"CREATE-EVENT"`:

```
open_tag = "<" + tag + ">"
close_tag = "</" + tag + ">"
@outbound_text.gsub!(/#{open_tag}/(.*)\/#{close_tag}/, '')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is what variable substitution into a regex looks like:

```
/#{open_tag}.*#{close_tag}/, ...
```

Pretend that the opening `/` and closing `/` of the regex are double quote marks and have at it.

Here's a full example:

```
tag = 'CREATE-EVENT'

open_tag = "<#{tag}>"
close_tag = "</#{tag}>"
any_text = ".*"

html_tag = /#{open_tag} 
            #{any_text}
            #{close_tag}/xm

@outbound_text = %q{
hello
 <CREATE-EVENT>
        <COLLECTION>PAM</COLLECTION>
        <EVENT-TYPE>
</CREATE-EVENT>
world
}

p @outbound_text.gsub!(html_tag, '')

--output:--
"\nhello\n \nworld\n"
```

Comment: Do I need a `/m`?  Didn't work without one, and if so, why?  @outbound_text.gsub!(/#{open_tag}(.*)#{close_tag}/m, '')

Comment: @Angela, In a regex `.` will not match a newline(\n).  Yes, that is a stupid default.  So, as a matter of course the `m` flag should always be used.  And the `x` flag should also be used as a matter of course--that way you can insert spaces into your regex to make it more readable, yet not have the spaces be part of the pattern.

Comment: I see, I am not familiar with the x flag, actually.  Would it be `/mx`?

Comment: Also quick question>  Suppose I have TWO `<CREATE-EVENT>` tags, is there a way to choose between deleting one and deleting both with a given statement?

Comment: @Angela, Both `/xm` and  `/mx` will work.   The String class has a method named `sub()` which will only change the first match.  gsub() stands for *global* sub, which looks for all matches.

Comment: @Angela, But as TinMan mentioned, Nokogiri is the way to parse html and xml.  If you learn a little Xpath, you can quickly locate the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, or last `<CREATE-EVENT>` tag and remove it.

Comment: I see. Let me go back and review in more detail what @tinman wrote.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with XML or HTML, don't use regular expressions unless the markup is extremely trivial and you own the task of generating it. Odds are very good that your code will break with a small change to the incoming data. Read "[Match All Occurrences of a Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80357)", which tries to explain the issues of using patterns to parse XML and HTML.

Instead, use something more resiliant, a parser. Here's how I'd do it:

```
xml = <<EOT
<CREATE-EVENT>
  <COLLECTION>PAM</COLLECTION>
  <EVENT-TYPE>survey_answer</EVENT-TYPE>
  <JSON-STRING>
    {
    question1:done,
    question2:done,
    question3:done,
    question4:done,
    question5:done,
    question6:done
    }
  </JSON-STRING>
</CREATE-EVENT>
<EMAIL>
  <ADDRESS>bot_client_id</ADDRESS>
  <SUBJECT>PAM responses for Wednesday October 07</SUBJECT>
  <BODY/>
</EMAIL>
EOT

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('<root>' + xml + '</root>')
```

Your XML example isn't syntactically correct because it's missing a root node and has unterminated `<EMAIL>` nodes so I added `</EMAIL>` and wrap `xml` with `<root>` when parsing it. In real life you'd pass the entire XML string, assuming it is valid XML using:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
```

Once it's parsed into a DOM, I can use:

```
doc.at('CREATE-EVENT').children.remove
```

to remove the child nodes of `<CREATE-EVENT>`, resulting in:

```
puts doc.to_xml
# >> <root><CREATE-EVENT/>
# >> <EMAIL>
# >>   <ADDRESS>bot_client_id</ADDRESS>
# >>   <SUBJECT>PAM responses for Wednesday October 07</SUBJECT>
# >>   <BODY/>
# >> </EMAIL>
# >> </root>
```

At this point `<CREATE-EVENT/>` is now empty.

If you want to substitute something into that node it's equally easy:

```
word = 'bar'
doc.at('CREATE-EVENT').children = "<foo>#{ word }</foo>"
```

which results in:

```
# >> <root><CREATE-EVENT><foo>bar</foo></CREATE-EVENT>
# >> <EMAIL>
# >>   <ADDRESS>bot_client_id</ADDRESS>
# >>   <SUBJECT>PAM responses for Wednesday October 07</SUBJECT>
# >>   <BODY/>
# >> </EMAIL>
# >> </root>
```

There are very few times I'd ever use `sub` or `gsub` to change HTML or XML. Instead I'd grab a parser first. It might not be as fast, but it's a lot more robust solution, which translates to being able to sleep through the night a lot more often.

You can read more about using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) by searching Stack Overflow ([nokogiri](/questions/tagged/nokogiri)), or the internet.

Comment: Thanks. The content isn't true XML. It uses xml like tags but for readability often has extra and unwanted tabs and end of lines. So I thought that would break any real xml parsing.

Comment: Technically the actual document is xml. But I am only working with one mode which passes a lot of extra spaces. If there were a way to make it fit the xml structure I would do it this way you suggest. However I also have a scenario where there may be more than one of the same tags. Eg more than one create event tag. I assumed that would break a xml parser. But am reading more to understand if that's the case.

Comment: Tabs and line-ends are considered white space and are ignored when between tags for the most part. That's true in XML and HTML. Your example data definitely looks like regular XML. You really need to supply a more accurate example of what you're dealing with. It doesn't sound like it's anything special or  difficult to handle.

Comment: @Angela, *But I am only working with one mode which passes a lot of extra spaces.*--Most(all?) xml parsers have a configuration setting that will ignore the newline and tabs between a parent element and a child element, i.e. the whitespace used to make xml look pretty. But if you use Xpath that isn't even necessary: you can obtain a collection of all the similarly named elements and pick and choose whichever ones you want--without having to worry about newlines being items in the collection.

Comment: As @7stud said, white space is generally there to make documents pretty for our eyes. Both CSS and XPath allow us to focus on the tags and gloss over the tabs and spaces and line-ends. When dealing with high speed transfer of big XML or HTML, we turn off the pretty-XML generation to more efficiently use the network, and the parser and selectors continue to work as we expect even without the "pretty". That's the beauty of using a parser vs. trying to search a text document where white space can be extremely significant.

Answer (score -1):

```
@outbound_text.gsub(/<CREATE-EVENT>(.*)<\/CREATE-EVENT>/m, '\1')
  #=> "\n\t\t\t\t<COLLECTION>PAM</COLLECTION>\n\t\t\t\t<EVENT-TYPE>
  #    survey_answer</EVENT-TYPE>\n\t\t\t\t<JSON-STRING>\n\t\t\t\t\t
  #    {\n\t\t\t\t\t question1:done,\n\t\t\t\t\t question2:done,
  #    \n\t\t\t\t\t question3:done,\n\t\t\t\t\t question4:done,
  #    \n\t\t\t\t\t question5:done,\n\t\t\t\t\t question6:done
  #    \n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t</JSON-STRING>\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n      <EMAIL>\n
  #        <ADDRESS>bot_client_id</ADDRESS>\n        <SUBJECT>PAM
  #    responses for Wednesday October 07</SUBJECT>\n        <BODY>\nHi, there"
```

I've broken the return string so it can be seen more easily. The problem is that you forgot `/m` (multiline) at the end of the regex.

Comment: *The problem is that you forgot /m (multiline) at the end of the regex.*--Look again!

Comment: @7stud, I don't follow. Look again at what?

Comment: The regex had more problems than not using /m.  I made a change to my answer, so  fell free to lobby for the points.

Comment: @7stud, yes, I forgot to mention that the hyphens need to be escaped, as I've done, but other than that, adding `/m` is all that's required. Your answer, which I upvoted, is better, however.

Comment: Outside of a character class, a hyphen is not a special regex character, e.g. the regex `/a-c/` will not match the strings `a` or `b` or `c`--it will match only the string `a-c`.  Anyway...onwards.

Comment: @7stud, ah yes, I got mixed up on that. Thanks, Will fix.