# Extract text between two character that appears multiple instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a string of email in a variable such as `"Bill Warner (abc Ltd.)" <bill@abc.com>, "Paula Warner" <paula@abc.com>`

I would like to create an array that extract each of the email and returns ["bill@abc.com","paula@abc.com"]

I find a way to make the extraction, using a custom function:

```
  def string_between_markers marker1, marker2
    self[/#{Regexp.escape(marker1)}(.*?)#{Regexp.escape(marker2)}/m, 1]
  end
```

Only issue, is that this works only once.
What would be the right method to extract each of the email address please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match all occurrences of a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80357/how-to-match-all-occurrences-of-a-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following and it works:

```
.scan(/\<(.*)\>/).flatten
```